# adding the results of two SQlite queries

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I want to add the results of two separate counting SQlite queries. Suppose I have 2 tables named `entries` and `scores` and have 2 queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM entries WHERE
    key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM scores)

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM scores WHERE
    value <= threshold
```

Maybe I could do something like this to get the sum of their results:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) from (
    SELECT key FROM entries WHERE
        key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM scores)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT key FROM scores WHERE
        value <= threshold
)
```

But is this a little too inefficient? This is called pretty often and may interfere with the UI's smoothness.

Thank you.

[EDIT] What I'm actually trying to do:

I'm making an app to help learning vocabulary. The `entries` table keeps 'static' data about word type, definition, etc. The `scores` table keeps information about how well you've learned the words (e.g. performance, scheduled next review time)

To check for the number of remaining words to learn/review, I count how many words do not exist in the `scores` table yet (i.e. never touched) or when the accumulated score is pretty low (i.e. needs reviewing).

The reason I don't merge those 2 tables into 1 (which would make my life much easier) is because sometimes I need to update the `entries` table either by inserting new words, deleting a few words, or updating their content, and I haven't found a simple way [to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace). If I simply do `INSERT OR REPLACE`, I will lose the information about scores.

Comment: by `COUNT(1)` you mean ...? It only accepts `*` or a column identifier. [See here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html).

Comment: it's a trick I learned somewhere to count the number of rows :D

Comment: Perhaps say, in English, what the *final intent* is :) To count the number of rows `COUNT(*)` should be used.

Comment: COUNT(1) and COUNT(\*) are effectively the same. COUNT(\*) means count the rows selecting all of the columns and COUNT(1) means count all of the rows selecting the integer 1.

Comment: @pst: I've updated my post explaining my goal.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a [UNION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator). A union combines the results from two queries. Try this (sorry it isn't tested, I don't have access to SQLite):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM entries
    WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM scores)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    FROM scores
    WHERE scores.value <= threshold
)
```

After reading the edit in your question explaining what you need to do, I think a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) would be more appropriate. This is a way of combining two tables into one query. Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM entries
LEFT JOIN score
    ON score.key = entries.key
WHERE score.value <= threshold
OR score.key is null
```

Comment: `UNION` will removed duplicate rows. It must be `UNION ALL`. See [Compound Select Statements](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).

Comment: @pst: I'm new to sql. Could you help me if you spot any mistake? Thank you very much :D

Comment: @Po I've added a comment to the main post.