# Insert or update in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Imagine a table that maps from a string to two integers. I would like to either insert a new row if the key is not in the table, or update the existing row by adding up the integers `(key, oldx+x, oldy+y)`. I'll be doing this a lot and I wonder if I can do this in one operation instead of first `SELECT` to check if the row exists and then `INSERT` or `UPDATE` with the sum as this probably will result in two lookups.

I'm new to SQL and I can't figure how to do this in an efficient way.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL, Oracle, Firebird, DB2, SQL Server, MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite supports `INSERT OR REPLACE`, which needs to be used with more care than most people think. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace/4330694#4330694) for details, and keep in mind the possibility of cascading deletes during replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Doing both will work:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET x=x+?, y=y+? WHERE key = ?; -- will do nothing if key not found

INSERT INTO TABLE (key, x, y)
SELECT ?, ?, ?
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE key = ?); -- will do nothing if key found
```

Only one will ever affect the data in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your database supports [Upsert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert).

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Insert record with key=k if it does not exist yet.
-- the zero's could also be handled by appropiate defaults for oldx,oldy 
INSERT INTO tab (key, oldx, oldy) select k,0,0 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab where key=k)
    ;

UPDATE tab
    SET oldx=oldx+y, oldy=oldy+y
    WHERE key = k
    ;
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. the SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS is returning a row for each row in the database not matching the final WHERE clause... as a result, it is inserting the new record multiple times.