# should I use "query" + "update/insert" or "insert/replace" in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table like this

```
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + URL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + SomeInfo + " TEXT,"
                + OtherInfo + " INTEGER"
                + ");");
```

So there is only one record for each URL value.
When the user visit a URL, I need neither insert a new row, or update an existing row if URL is presented
I could think of 2 ways:

1. `SQLiteDatabase.query` first and apply an update if there is one
2. Always use `SQLiteDatabase.replace`, in case the UNIQUE constraint fail, sqlite will replace the record.

   Which approach is better?
   Are there other suggestions?
   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seems to be a commom issue (which I faced recently too) I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace/4330694#4330694) which might be helpful.