# SQLite unique index by 2 fields

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Date_Table" 
("Year" DATETIME , 
 "Month1" INTEGER, 
 "Month2" INTEGER,
 "ID" INTEGER)
```

Then i created inique index of 2 columns

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX field1_field2_idx ON table_name(Year, ID)
```

When i done i want to insert if there is none of this kind record and replace if there are.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Date_Table(Year, Month1, Month2, ID) Values(2012, 1, ?,1)
```

Everything is as it should be at this point, but if i do this insert:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Date_Table(Year, Month1, Month2, ID) Values(2012, ?, 1,1)
```

It replace all record deleting Month1 to NULL, but i want just update in that row Month2 column.

Maybe someone could help me on this. It's about SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is duplicate: 
[SQLite - UPSERT *not* INSERT or REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace)

For your schema try something like:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Date_Table (Year, Month1,  Month2, ID) 
Values(
   2012, 
   (select Month1 from Data_Table where Year = 2012 and ID = 1),
   1,1)
```

**EDITED due OP comment:**

Instead of values you can specify a [select on insert](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Date_Table (Year, Month1, Month2, ..., Month12, ID) 
select
   2012 as Year, 
   Month1,
   Month2,
   ...
   1 as Month12,
   ID
from Data_Table 
where Year = 2012 and ID = 1
```

Disclaimer: not tested.

Comment: But what if my table would be 12 Month. Month1,Month2 to Month12.

Then i would need 11 selects ?