# Android Update record if data exist

Tags: android

I have this code below which consist on my Android app DatabaseHelper Class, Currently i have hardcoded a row of data inside my database which is the `Barcode(263924)` and `Quantity(1)`.

But the problem is i'm currently trying to make it so that when the user adds the same barcode number i hardcoded into my database the quantity will +1 and not create a new row.

Sorry im currently new to android any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

MainActivity Codes

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String barcodes = result.getText();
    final String quantitys = "1";
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
    alert1.show();
    AddData(barcodes,quantitys);

}

public void AddData(String barcodes,String quantitys){
    boolean insertData = myDB.addData(barcodes,quantitys);

    if(insertData==true){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully Entered Data!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Something went wrong :(.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Database Code

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scan.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scan_data";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "BARCODE";
    public static final String COL3 = "QUANTITY";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " BARCODE TEXT, QUANTITY TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);

        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL2,263924);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL3,1);

        db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String code, String quant) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, code);
        contentValues.put(COL3, quant);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SQLite Insert or Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311727/android-sqlite-insert-or-update)

Answer (score 1):

For that, I could proceed as follows:

```java
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scan.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scan_data";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "BARCODE";
    public static final String COL3 = "QUANTITY";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " BARCODE TEXT, QUANTITY TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);

        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL2,263924);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL3,1);

        db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String code, String quant) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return isValueExists(code,db,quant);

    }

    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }
    public Boolean isValueExists(String barcode,SQLiteDatabase db, String quant){
        Cursor cursor= db.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[]      {"ID"},"ID=?",new String[]{barcode},null,null,null,"1");
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
             //if it exists then update
               try{
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put(COL1,cursor.getString(0));
                    cv.put(COL2,cursor.getString(1));
                  cv.put(COL3,String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(2)+1)));
                  sqLiteDataBase.update(TABLE_NAME,cv,"BARCODE=?",new String[]{barcode});
                     cursor.close();

            }catch(Exception e){}

        return true;
                }else{
                    cursor.close();
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, code);
        contentValues.put(COL3, quant);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        db.close();
        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }}
            }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but how do i implement that into my current codes

Comment: copy the code and insert it in the database helper class. then before calling `addData`, test if the value exists by passing the barcode into parameter if it returns false then continue instructions inside `addData`. do you want me to edit the answer and insert the line?

Comment: Yes if you dont mind can you edit the awnser and insert the lines? I have updated my question.

Comment: i have added the codes into my project but nothing happen?

Comment: Is it showing any error? If yes post in comment. Any message? isn't it even inserting? I'd to test your project in local if possible

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    id NOT NULL INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

A primary key is a column or group of columns used to identify the uniqueness of rows in a table. Each table has one and only one primary key.

Source: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-primary-key/