# SQLite UPSERT with 2 constraints

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sql table with 3 columns, none of which is UNIQUE ( but the pair name + role is ):

```
 Name | Role | Votes
```

What I need to do is, write an sqllite query that stick to the following rules :

1. If a row with the given name and role already exist, votes is
   incremented by 1
2. If not, a new row is created with Votes = 1

I've looked into INSERT OR REPLACE and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace) great post but it doesn't seem to help me that much, and I'm not even sure INSERT OR REPLACE is a viable option, since something like

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO words (name,role,votes) 
VALUES ('foo','bar', coalesce((
    select votes from words where name = 'foo' and role='bar'),0)+1)
```

always insterts and never replace

Comment: It's not a duplicate, since none of my columns is unique or can be set as such

Comment: you only need to add compound unique column `CONSTRAINT tb_UQ UNIQUE (Name, RoleID)` and the link i gave you will work.

Comment: And you are right :) in any case, I think that the query i posted, once added the constraint to the table, is better than the one you linked, isn't it?

Comment: i was wondering why you need to get the `counter`?

Comment: What do you mean by get the counter ? you want to know what's that table for, or the reason of the select?

Comment: the reason for `select`.

Comment: to increment by 1 the former value in case there's one ... right, that's votes, not counter, my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to create unique index over your 2 columns for this to work:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX words_name_role_idx ON words (name,role)
```

Note that you do not create unique index for any single column, but for combination of 2 as a whole.

After that, your `REPLACE INTO` statement should start working correctly:

```
REPLACE INTO words (name,role,votes) VALUES ('foo','bar',
    coalesce((
        SELECT votes FROM words
        WHERE name = 'foo' AND role='bar'),0
    )+1
)
```

(note that I have changed `counter` to `votes` above).

Answer (score 0):

This query will update your record with +1.

```
update todo set text='raj',complete='raj',pk=((SELECT pk FROM todo where text='raj' and complete='raj')+1) where (SELECT pk FROM todo where text='raj' and complete='raj')
```

**EDIT YOUE QUERY**

```
update words set name='foo',role='bar', votes =((SELECT votes FROM words where name='foo' and role='bar')+1) where (SELECT votes FROM words where name='foo' and role='bar')
```

And make insert query if this condition will not true.