# update method in sqlite didn't throw Exception?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, exception, try-catch

I'm getting information about items from the web and I want my app to check if certain rows exist. If they do exist then the app should update those rows, otherwise it should create new rows:

```
try {
    mDb.execSQL("UPDATE ["
    + ParseReciverAddList.tableName
    + "] SET purchased = " + pCheck
    + " WHERE id =" + (thisId));
    mDb.execSQL("UPDATE ["
    + ParseReciverAddList.tableName
    + "] SET name = '" + (PName)
    + "' WHERE id =" + (thisId));
    mDb.execSQL("UPDATE ["
    + ParseReciverAddList.tableName
    + "] SET quantity = '" + (pQuantity)
    + "' WHERE id =" + (thisId));
    Log.d("p", "e");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("p", "ne");
    mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO ["+ParseReciverAddList.tableName+"] VALUES ("+thisId+","+pCheck+", '"+PName+"','"+pQuantity+"');");
}
```

I figure I'll try to update it and if it throws `Exception` then it means the rows don't exist and it will create it.

However, I'm running into a problem: even if the row doesn't exist it doesn't throw `Exception`. Any ideas as to why it's not triggering the `catch` clause when the rows already exist?

Comment: and what kind of exception? add here logcat please.

Comment: it wont trow exception , thats the problem . i want him to trow exception if row doesnt exist but he wont .

Comment: You can use `mDb.query` to know  if row exist.

Comment: Even if it did throw an exception, for the record, that's a terrible way to control execution logic (with exceptions). Just check if the data actually exists first so you'll know the state. Or you could look into the concept of "upsert" and "insert or replace" (though the latter can be tricky, make sure you know what you're doing or you'll clobber data. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I'm running into a problem: even if the row doesn't exist it
>   doesn't throw Exception. Any ideas as to why it's not triggering the
>   catch clause when the rows already exist?

Reason is that [`execSQL()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) throws `SQLException` only in the case if your `SQL` String is invalid. But your problem is that if row doesn't exist simply `UPDATE` statement won't be applied but it does not mean that `SQL` String is incorrect.

Solution is to use for example API method [`update()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL) that returns number of rows affected and if it will return 0 simply perform `INSERT`.

**Pseudocode:**

```
int rowsAffected = db.update("table", values, "id = ?", 
                   new String[] {String.valueOf(thisId)});
if (rowsAffected == 0) {
   // perform insert
}
```