# differentiate between update and inset in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

In SQlite how can I say if a row exists update it else createEntry?
basically I want to have a table with single row and update it whenever single button pressed or so.

```
entry.open();
if(the row already exist)
entry.updateContact(1, Double.toString(db1), Double.toString(db2), Double.toString(db3));
else
entry.createEntry(Double.toString(db1), Double.toString(db2), Double.toString(db3));
entry.close();
```

Comment: You want to do an UpSert, check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace

Comment: the best and simple way is to create a single now when db is created first time and then update rest of time , this way your pre checking computation will lessen

Comment: How can I limit the creation of db to single row?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to `INSERT OR REPLACE`. There's a blog post on this topic at http://www.buzzingandroid.com/2013/01/sqlite-insert-or-replace-through-contentprovider/