# Inserting values only if the record doesn't exist already

Tags: sql, sqlite

am using sqlite3 database. I have inserted set of device_ids(unique) in a table called device, this is done when the table is empty. But when i try to insert the ids again which contains some new id's it is throwing error because of uniqueness.

```
 device_all_id.each do |device_id|

     insert into device (Device_id) values ('#{device_id.first}') where  where Device_id <> '#{device_id.first}'

 end
```

So i want to check whether the record is already there before inserting device_ids, so i tried 'IF EXISTS' query but that too throwing as syntax error.

could anyone please help me out of this..

Comment: Please don't use tags that don't relate to your question

Answer (score 1):

Checking before inserting will require the database to answer two queries, and it won't really reduce your error handling. (You *have* to trap errors. There are a lot of ways an update can go wrong.) You're almost always better off just

- executing the INSERT statement,
- trapping errors, and
- taking appropriate action to resolve the error.

It's not clear from your question whether an UPSERT might work for you. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330694/562459).