# Insert or update a row in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, upsert

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330694/1492861) but I'm not sure it does what I want to. It looks like it updates ALL rows in the table, where I only want to update one.

My table is very simple:

```
MacAddress           |    Name
1C-6F-65-C6-20-0B    |    Logan-PC
DE-AD-BE-EF-F0-0D    |    PC1
...
```

`MacAddress` is the PK and I want to simply be able to update Name if it exists or add a new row if it does not, given the `MacAddress` as references and a `Name` string.

This is the first time I'm using SQLite so I may just not be understanding Eric B's answer correctly.

Comment: `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO MyTable ("MacAddress ", "Name") VALUES ("1C-6F-65-C6-20-0B", "PC2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you posted seems to work well for me assuming your MacAddress is a primary key in your table.

```
insert or replace into yourtable (macaddress, name)
values ('1C-6F-65-C6-20-0B', 'Logan-PC');

insert or replace into yourtable (macaddress, name)
values ('1C-6F-65-C6-20-0B', 'Logan-PC-Updated');
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a4f56/1)

This will result in a single row, with Logan-PC-Updated as the updated name.

NOTE: If your MacAddress is not your primary key, then this method will not work.