# Insert or update sqlite3

Tags: insert, sqlite

I'm facing a small problem here. I have a table with multiple columns but what i want to is write a sqlite query that to be used in my python script so that i can insert if the key is not found or else update other values if the key is already found. I researched a little and came through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace) but my concern in my content it's not working and keeps on adding the new rows even if it exists.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace) i wrote a query since my update/insert is dependent on a column called as id which is a foreign key constraint to this table. Other two columns that i want to update are say name and role. so what i want to do is insert all three if the id is not found. if found then see if it has got same values or not for other two columns and update it. here is my attempt.

`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tblExample(id, name, role) 
VALUES ( COALESCE((SELECT id FROM tblExample WHERE id = 1),'1'),'name','role');`

But it's still inserting new rows. why? how can i avoid it? any simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Duplicate detection is based on the `PRIMARY KEY` definition of the table you're inserting into.  If you have not explicitly defined a primary key on the table, it will use the unique `ROW_ID` value (and you'll always get a new row).  What is the `PRIMARY KEY` for this table?
2. `INSERT OR REPLACE` really does a replacement of the row, not an UPDATE.  That means that if a duplicate is detected and the REPLACE pathway is chosen, any columns not given values in the statement will be updated to their `DEFAULT` values *or to NULL if no `DEFAULT` is specified*.  In other words, if your table has an additional column called `city`, and a row is replaced, then `city` will be `NULL`, not whatever value it had in the original row.

Comment: The table has it's own primary key which is autoincrement. The id that i want to use to update is the foreign key to that table @larry

Comment: INSERT OR REPLACE will only use the PRIMARY KEY for duplicate resolution (actually, it will use any unique key).  It cannot use a FOREIGN KEY since those are not unique and wouldn't tell the engine which row to replace if replacement were required.  If the FOREIGN KEY is *also* unique, you will need to create a UNIQUE INDEX on it as well.

Comment: can you provide an alternate solution to my problem then?

Comment: If you have a qualified unique column (or combination of columns) on which to base the updates, then declare that as either the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE INDEX on the table.  Once you do that, SQLite will have enough information to detect key conflicts.  If you *don't* have a unique set of columns to base conflict detection on, then you don't have a sufficiently well-defined problem.

Comment: well i'm new to sqlite so what i did is i used the way i used to create database on SQL server and just implemented it here...so all my table have is one primary key(autoincrement), one foreign key and some columns. I'm using foreign key for insertion because that is the one i'm using to fetch my values from another source. Any alternatives that you can suggest me to avoid this problem would deeply be appreciated!

Comment: i don't have a qualified unique column other than the primary key itself. All others can be repetitive and even null

Comment: Then you do not have a problem that can be solved.  Ask yourself -- how is SQLite going to decide when to add a row and when to replace an existing row?  Without some set of columns on which to base the decision, there's no way to make the decision.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35783/discussion-between-nottyshinchan-and-larry-lustig)

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but the trick is to make sure your id, which I assume is the primary key of this table, matches an existing id, else it won't see it as a duplicate record.

Comment: Nope, it's the foreign key of the table the primary key is a separate column