# JDBC/SQLite batch insert with foreign key constraints

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, foreign-keys, bulkinsert

I'm trying to import data from CSV files to a database, but table A has foreign key constraints table B. What I want is to insert the data into A and update the relevant row in B if the foreign key matches a primary key in B (and there are no other issues); otherwise nothing should happen. Currently, I'm doing (a slightly more complicate version of) the following:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

for (row in b.csv){
    INSERT INTO b
    VALUES ("b_key", NULL, NULL);
}

for (row in a.csv){
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO a 
    VALUES ("a_key", "b_key", ...);

    UPDATE OR IGNORE b 
    SET x = "X", y = "Y"
    WHERE key = "b_key";
}
```

The result of this is eventually a.csv will contain a row for which the "b_key" is not in table b, at which point the entire batch update will fail with the exception "foreign key constraint failed." Anyone know a simple (or even not-simple) way that I can get this to work?

Comment: Why does the data have invalid b keys? And why can't you simply check whether the key exists?

Comment: 1. Because it's part of a homework assignment. 

2. My first idea to avoid this was to do a query that checked wither the key exists in b before doing the insert and update. This was unusably slow. My next idea was to put all the b_keys in a hash set and check that they existed there before the insert and update. This  failed to prevent foreign key errors. I'm trying to work out the kinks with that method, but it still seems like there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: Checking for existence of a key is not slow if you have [proper indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) (and you should have them anyway because the built-in FK checks need them too). Are you using one transaction for all updates?

Answer (score 1):

1) Switch the order of the `INSERT` the `UPDATE` in the second loop. That way, "b" will be set before "a" requires it.

2) Use `INSERT OR REPLACE` rather than `UPDATE` for the "b" keys. More on how this works and why it is good at: [SQLite - UPSERT *not* INSERT or REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace). Basically, you will guarantee that you have the key in "b" before putting anything into the "a" table.