# SQLite - update (not replace) if exists, else insert

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I'm trying to insert data into an sqlite db which may already exist. If it exists, I want to add to it (NOT replace!). I'm not really sure how to do this.

something like this (not sure if my syntax is right)

```
case
  when exists(select * from Link where word1='%s' and word2='%s')
    then update Link set n = %d + (select n from Link where word1='%s' and word2='%s')
  else
    insert into Link values('%s', '%s', %d)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite - UPSERT \*not\* INSERT or REPLACE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite you can do `INSERT OR REPLACE` rather than a normal `INSERT` if you've defined a primary key on your table.  If another row in the table already exists with the primary key you're attempting to insert, it gets overwritten.

So, if you made a compound primary key on your table consisting of `word1` and `word2`, you could do:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO link (word1, word2, n)
SELECT 
    x.word1, x.word2, x.n + COALESCE(l.n, 0)
FROM ( SELECT '%s' AS word1, '%s' AS word2, %d AS n ) x
LEFT JOIN link l ON x.word1 = l.word1 AND x.word2 = l.word2
```