# UPSERT in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, upsert

I don't want to use `REPLACE INTO` because it's basically a `DELETE` and `INSERT` and it's complicated to use the data from the old columns.

`INSERT OR IGNORE` is a bit of a hack because all errors are ignored, so this is not an option.

I've read a [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx) which uses the following:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

I like this approach really much, but I don't know how I can implement this `IF-clause` with the `@@ROWCOUNT` in SQLite, this is what I got:

```
SELECT CASE (SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE id=2)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
    END)
WHEN 1
  UPDATE t set a='pdf' WHERE id=2;
ELSE
  INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES ('pdf');
END
```

the `SELECT CASE` seems to be the only way to use a `CASE-clause` in SQLite because everything else throws an syntax error. But it's also not possible to use a `UPDATE`- or `INSERT`-statement in the `SELECT CASE`, so this throws an error.

I've tried the following

```
UPDATE t set a='pdf' WHERE id=2;
CASE WHEN (changes()=0) THEN
    INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES ('pdf');
END
```

but this doesn't work, because the `CASE-clause` throws an syntax error.

**can someone provide an example using `@@ROWCOUNT` for an UPSERT in SQLite?**

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` is a feature of T-SQL not available in SQLite, nor does SQLite have the IF or CASE statements as you're trying to use them. If you really need UPSERT you may need to accept that "it's complicated" and either use the [solution given in question 418898](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace/4330694#4330694) or check the result of `SELECT changes()` from application code and perform the INSERT based on that.

Comment: The `@@ROWCOUNT` is borrowed from the blog article I refer to, sorry for the bad articulation. I like the idea with `SELECT changes()`, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQLite has no built-in UPSERT-like statement that doesn't delete the old record.

You should check the number of changes in your program, and execute the INSERT conditionally.

However, if you really want to do this in SQL, it's possible; but you have to use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` form so that you are able to insert zero records, if needed:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE t SET a = 'pdf' WHERE id = 2;
INSERT INTO t(id, a) SELECT 2, 'pdf' WHERE changes() = 0;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Why is everbody using `REPLACE INTO` or `INSERT OR IGNORE` then?  This solution works like a charm and looks beautiful, thanks!

Comment: `INSERT OR IGNORE` is using because it consumes single SQL statement.

Comment: what if another thread was updating a row and changes() was changed between the two query statement?

Comment: @alizx When using a transaction, other threads cannot interfere.

Comment: according to documentation its per database connection not transaction.

Comment: "If a separate thread makes changes on the same database connection while sqlite3_changes() is running then the value returned is unpredictable and not meaningful." SQLite documentation

Comment: @alizx When two threads share a connection, they also share the connection's transaction. Proper multithreading requires using using separate connections.

Comment: @CL. I cannot get what does sharing a transaction mean. can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @alizx There is a 1:1 relationship between a connection and a transaction. If you want separate transactions, you need separate connections.

Answer (score 2):

You should use sqlite API in this case and write "IF logic" in your application.

```
sqlite3_prepare16_v2(stmt1, "UPDATE t SET a=? WHERE id=?");

sqlite3_prepare16_v2(stmt2, "INSERT INTO t(id, a) VALUES(?, ?)");

for(...) // iterate by rows to be updated/inserted
{
    //set parameter values for stmt1

    sqlite3_step(stmt1);
    if( !sqlite3_changes(dbh) )
    {
        //set parameter values for stmt2
        sqlite3_step(stmt2);
    }
}
```