# SQL with C# - UPDATE not working but INSERT does work

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite with C# and have a table in a database that I want to insert a row into if the table is empty otherwise update the row in the table if there is a row in there. This table will only ever have one row so it isn't necessary to constrain the UPDATE command. If I comment out the update part and row count part to just leave the insert part then it inserts a row fine but the code below to implement the functionality I want throws an error in Visual Studio and I can't figure out why.

```
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE details SET (initials = @init, participantID = @ID, affectedSide = @side, age = @age, comments = @comm) IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT INTO details (initials, participantID , affectedSide , age, comments) VALUES (@init, @ID, @side, @age, @comm)";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@init", InitalsTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", IDTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@side", side);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", ageindex);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comm", ParticipantText.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

The error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in
>   System.Data.SQLite.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: SQL logic error or missing database
>
> near "(": syntax error

Comment: What error does it show ?

Comment: Please mentions your error here

Comment: I'm not working with SQLite, but I doubt, that command like this will be parsed by client library you use. Split it into two separate commands, run update command first, and, if its `ExecuteNonQuery` will return 0, run insert command.

Comment: I have added the error @MattMurdock

Comment: For trying sake, Put braces around your IF statement.

Comment: I have added the error @NeerajSharma

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately @MattMurdock

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` is T-SQL, `changes()` is the equivalent for SQLite, which also has no `IF` construct.  Run the insert `where changes() = 0`

Comment: @Dennis it's working with your suggestion, thanks! I did have to remove the brackets as suggested

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. that explains why it isn't working. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work, can you please give an example of the entire command

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323174/upsert-in-sqlite /  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @AlexK. in the comments on my question: SQLite does not have @@ROWCOUNT nor an IF construct and so different ways of achieving the desired functionality can be achieved differently. See these links:

[UPSERT in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323174/upsert-in-sqlite)

[SQL with C# - UPDATE not working but INSERT does work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017882/sql-with-c-sharp-update-not-working-but-insert-does-work/34023441#34023441)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, Change your update query

```
UPDATE details SET initials = @init, participantID = @ID, affectedSide = @side, age = @age, comments = @comm IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT INTO details (initials, participantID , affectedSide , age, comments) VALUES (@init, @ID, @side, @age, @comm)
```

Comment: Still getting an error. Additional information: SQL logic error or missing database: near "IF": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Just close the logic in stored procedure and run it with your parameteres

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM details) > 0
BEGIN
  UPDATE details
  SET initials = @init, participantID = @ID, affectedSide = @side, age = @age,           comments = @comm
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO details 
  (initials
  ,participantID 
  ,affectedSide 
  ,age
  ,comments) 
  VALUES 
  (@init
  ,@ID
  ,@side
  ,@age
  ,@comm)
END