# How to do Upsert in Vlang

Tags: sqlite, vlang

Currently, the `ORM` for `V` only supports `select`, `update`, and `insert`. I would like to do a more complicated `upsert` like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO Settings (Key, Value)
VALUES (?0, ?1)
ON CONFLICT(Key)
DO UPDATE
SET Key = ?0,
    Value = ?1;`
```

But it looks like [from the docs](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/examples/database/sqlite.v) there is no exposure for doing an update like this. So, I would need to clean the inserted/updated values myself.

Is there a way to do direct SQL with variables directly? Am I missing something?

Another option I would have would be:

```
setting := Settings {
    key: key
    value: value
}
sql r.db {
    insert setting into Settings
}
sql r.db {
    update Settings set value = value where key == key
}
```

Although the above works it isn't very elegant and requires two calls to the DB. Is there a way to do direct queries with arguments?

Comment: I'd suggest throwing away the ORM and just writing your own SQL so you can get full control of the database and its features.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really a C programmer, so it is much more difficult for me to go down that path. But I think you are probably right. I'll just have to learn it. But V I can copy some of the V code to learn I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The vlang Sqlite library (not the Orm) has [a method](https://modules.vlang.io/sqlite.html#DB.exec) that can execute raw SQL against the db and return raw row data.

You could create your upsert query using the information in [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323174/upsert-in-sqlite) and execute it as a string against the DB.

Something like this maybe (you'll have to test it against your particular database until it works):

```golang
r.db.exec("UPDATE Settings SET value = 'value' WHERE id = 2;
INSERT INTO Settings(key, value) SELECT 2, 'value' WHERE changes() = 0;")
```

**Do not use this in production**. Unfortunately, the `exec` function does not santize inputs or pass in parameterized values. This means that you will be vulnerable to [sql injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) by default.

Comment: `r.db.exec` was confusing to me. I think DB API has changed a bit in V 0.3.3. I did: `import db.sqlite 

db := sqlite.connect('db.sqlite') db.exec('SQL statement')`