# NS_ERROR_FAILURE on Duplicate Key with SQL Request

Tags: sqlite

I have tried to run this request on my database:

```
INSERT INTO scnScenarios (id,version,description,author,created_at,updated_at,tailNumber,flightLegCounter,name ) 
VALUES ('98','','','','2014-05-21 22:04:05','','9001','12','bolo') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=last_insert_rowid() , description='',author='';
```

Returns this error:

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: INSERT INTO scnScenarios (id,version,description,author,created_at,updated_at,tailNumber,flightLegCounter,name ) 
VALUES ('98','','','','2014-05-21 22:04:05','','9001','12','bolo') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=last_insert_rowid() , description='',author=''; [ near "ON": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite's [INSERT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) has no ON DUPLICATE KEY clause.

The easiest way to handle this is with multiple statements: try the UPDATE first, and if the record does not exist (if the number of affected records is zero), execute the INSERT.

See also [SQLite - UPSERT *not* INSERT or REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace).