# SQLite insert if not exists else update

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, insert

So I saw some similar questions here but I just could not understand them.

My table:

```
'timestamp' int(30) NOT NULL,
'clientguid' varchar(32) NOT NULL,
'clientip' varchar(32) NOT NULL,
'serverip' varchar(32) NOT NULL)
```

I have 4 variables

```
$TimeStamp
$ClientGUID
$ClientIP
$ServerIP
```

My query should do this:
if there is a row with `clientguid` that matches `$ClientGUID`:

```
UPDATE 'mytablename'
SET 'timestamp' = '$TimeStamp','clientip' = '$ClientIP','serverip' = '2.2.2.24'
WHERE 'mytablename'.'clientguid' = '$ClientGUID');
```

If there is not a row matching that:

```
INSERT INTO 'mytablename' ('timestamp','clientguid','clientip','serverip') 
VALUES($TimeStamp,'$ClientGUID', '$ClientIP', '$ServerIP');
```

I don't have to worry about escaping and validating, that has already been done
I just need a statement that will accomplish this. :)

Comment: That post is SQL Server 2008, not SQLite :P

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace .........................

Comment: see @edelwater's duplicate suggestion then... doesn't look like you're the first one having asked this one... search is your good friend ;)

Comment: edelwater, I saw this question but I'm unsure how to specify which column I want to look for a match on. If I just do this update SQL command, then is it updating the first row with a matching server ip? client ip? I would specifically like to do it by client GUID.

Comment: In 418898 notice the "select" in the answer

Comment: @dotNNJ what is your Unique/PK? Is $ClientGUID unique or not over your rows? Ergo: do you want to do massive updates or just only 1 ?

Comment: Only one at a time. There can be duplicate serverip, clientip, and timestamp values, but never two of the same clientguid

Comment: I'd recommend Sam Saffron's answer; it's the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

If you set unique key on your table, then you can first do it insert and if error duplicity record then catch them and do it update. This usually faster then some how first existence of row and then do it update.

Answer (score -1):

Create an UNIQUE index for colomn clientguid
Then tou can use INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (timestanp, clientguid,clientip, serverip)
VALUES(NOW(), $clientguid, '$clientip', '$serverip')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    timestamp = NOW(),
    clientip = VALUES(clientip),
    serverip = VALUES(serverip)
```

Comment: This does not work in SQLite.