# in mysql, how to remove the unique key on duplicate, and still insert a new row in the same command?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table for users, and it has a column `gcm_id` for push notifications to android.
I set this column to be unique since a user might logout and login on the same device so they will have the same gcm_id.

I want the behaviour to be as followed:

When an update for a user's `gcm_id` column is request, if the specific `gcm_id` already exists, change it to null and continue to update as usuall on the request row.

I'll give an example. Say I have the following entries in my table:

```
index | user_name | gcm_id
------+-----------+-------
1     | Tom       | 123
2     | John      | NULL
```

If Tom logs out and logs in as John, the client will want to update the gcm_id for John to be `123`. But `gcm_id` column should be unique. So in that case, I would like that the mysql server will change Tom's `gcm_id` to `NULL` and set John's `gcm_id` to be `123`.

All I've seen so far in relation to `ON DUPLICATE` syntax is to make mysql update **only** the existing row **instead** of creating a new one. I want to do both.

Is that possible in a single mysql command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kind of do it, see **[this question about upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace)** (don't know if applicable to  MySQL though).

But I would still **use a separate table for device ids**, with only `gcm_id` and `user_id` fields.

With your current design you don't have an ability to have the same user associated with two different devices. Using an extra table you would be able to trivially remedy that by making `user_id` non-unique. That alone makes the change worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible. An easier thing to do however may be to just set Tom's `gcm_id` to `NULL` when he logs out rather than having to change both rows in one mysql command.