# Insert or Update Table SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table looks something like

```
table (id, attribute, value, expires, static)
```

I'd like to be able to update this table for new values of value, expires or static when an entry for an id/attribute pair that already exists.  I would like to create a new entry for every new id/attribute pair and every new id.

I am new at using sqlite and have seen a few posts similar to my problem like
[SQLite - UPSERT *not* INSERT or REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace/4330694#4330694)
but they do not fully address what I'm trying to do.  Maybe its my approach and I need a different table format.

Please let me know your thoughts/suggestions.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: C++, using the DML commands

Comment: Are you using the C API or some C++ library?

Comment: This is all being done in Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the logic into your program:

```cpp
bool ok = query.exec("UPDATE ...");
...
if (query.numRowsAffected() == 0) {
    ok = query.exec("INSERT ...");
    ...
}
```