# Weird behavior with SQLite insert or replace

Tags: python, sqlite, insert, increment

I am trying to increment the count of a row in an SQLite database if the row exists, or add a new row if it doesn't exist the way it is done in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace) post. However I'm getting some weird behavior when I try to execute this SQL proc many times in quick succession. As an example I tried running this code:

```
db = connect_to_db()
c = db.cursor()
for i in range(10):
    c.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO subject_words (subject, word, count) VALUES ('subject', 'word', COALESCE((SELECT count + 1 FROM subject_words WHERE subject = 'subject' AND word = 'word'), 1));")
    db.commit()
db.close()
```

And it inserted the following into the database

```
sqlite> select * from subject_words;
subject|word|1
subject|word|2
subject|word|2
subject|word|2
subject|word|2
subject|word|2
subject|word|2
subject|word|2
subject|word|2
subject|word|2
```

Which totals to 19 entries of the word 'word' with subject 'subject'. Can anyone explain this weird behavior?

Comment: No, that's 10 entries, one for every iteration of your loop. What were you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting a single entry with the third value 10

Comment: Do you have any constraints that would be violated by this insertion, so that the replace clause is triggered?

Comment: No I didn't add any constraints to any of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've understood what INSERT OR REPLACE actually does. The REPLACE clause would only come into play if it was not possible to do the insertion, because a unique constraint was violated. An example might be if your `subject` column was the primary key.

However, without any primary keys or other constraints, there's nothing being violated by inserting multiple rows with the same subject; so there's no reason to invoke the REPLACE clause.

Answer (score 1):

That operation is much easier to write and understand if you do it with two SQL statements:

```
c.execute("""UPDATE subject_words SET count = count + 1
             WHERE subject = ? AND WORD = ?""",
          ['subject', 'word'])
if c.rowcount == 0:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO subject_words (subject, word, count) VALUES (?,?,?)",
              ['subject', 'word', 1])
```

This does not require a UNIQUE constraint on the columns you want to check, and is not any less efficient.