# how to import data from postgres database to android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, postgresql

I have a Postgres database server and I need to download the table records from postgres to tablet android (sqlite database). Is there a feature in Android to do this?

Example: There is a customer table in postgres and i need to import this table to sqlite in android.

Any tips are welcome.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by dumbing database in sql file from postgres and importing it to sqlite.

Dump database in a sql file.

```
pg_dump dbname > outfile.sql
```

Ref: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html

Import database from sql dump file

```
sqlite> .read outfile.sql
```

Ref: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

You can dump specific table in postgres using following command:

```
pg_dump  --table=table dbname > outfile.sql
```

Comment: That is a valid answer, but i need update the database if the record exists.

Comment: you can replace 
`INSERT INTO` with `INSERT OR REPLACE` in mysql dump file.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace

Comment: @Fabricio not agree. there are a lot of different details inside. you need to replace some true's ad false's. remove extra commands etc... check here more detailed review https://medium.com/@andreypu/how-to-port-postgresql-db-to-sqlite-db-e991b0d82287

Answer (score 0):

...also you should clean your dump file before conversion
replace all true -> 't', false -> 'f'(but don't touch true and false in `CREATE TABLE`s)
remove all lines started with `SET`, `SELECT`, `ALTER` etc.
remove all mentions of `SCHEMA`. and `OWNER`
(sqlite does not understand it)
add `BEGIN;` as a first line and `END;` as - the last one
between them should stay only commands `CREATE TABLE` and your data
such as [INSERT INTO](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)
and check data types - SQLite [does not understand](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) `BIG_INT` (and not only him)