# SQLite: update if exist or insert with select from different table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables A, B and C.

```
A:
----------------
index_a | value
----------------

B:
----------------
index_b | value
----------------

C:
----------------------------
index_c | table_name | value_c
----------------------------
```

Now user gives me **value ,Table name and new_value_c**. Table name can be A or B and value is respective value of table A or B. Now if there exist a record matching given value in given table we will get index of that table (index_a or index_b) and try to insert that in table C if there is no record with that index and table name otherwise we will update new_value_c. If there is no record matching value and table name then we will not do nothing.

I know we can use one **SELECT** to get index of table A or B and then **INSERT OR REPLACE INTO** table C. I am wondering if it can be achieved in single sql command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite - UPSERT \*not\* INSERT or REPLACE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace)

Comment: In passing, and without knowing where your table structure came from nor why, my first thought is that it may be better with one "AB" table with columns `index`, `type` and `value`.  This would almost certainly simplify your SQL, particularly if there were ever more than just "A" and "B" tables in the future.

Comment: @aleroot i think my question is different from that link although it uses that but it need more then that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`INSERT OR REPLACE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) and `SELECT` in one statement. Try this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO C (index_c, table_name, value_c)
SELECT index_a, 'A', ?3 FROM A WHERE value = ?1 AND 'A' = ?2
 UNION
SELECT index_b, 'B', ?3 FROM B WHERE value = ?1 AND 'B' = ?2
```

There: `?1` - placeholder for **value**, `?2` - **table name** and `?3` - **new_value_c**