# Simulating UPSERT in presence of UNIQUE constraints

Tags: sql, sqlite

Simulating UPSERT was already [discusssed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace) before. In my case though, I have PRIMARY KEY and additional UNIQUE constraint, and I want upsert semantic with respect to primary key - replacing existing row if it exists, while checking the unique constraint.

Here's an attempt using insert-or-replace:

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (id INTEGER, name TEXT, s INTEGER, 
                   PRIMARY KEY (id, s), 
                   UNIQUE (name, s));

insert or replace into test values (1, "a", 0);
insert or replace into test values (1, "a", 0);
insert or replace into test values (2, "b", 0);
insert or replace into test values (2, "a", 0);
```

The last statement is replaces both rows. This is documented behavior of 'insert or replace', but not what I want.

Here is an attempt with "on conflict replace":

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (id INTEGER, name TEXT, s INTEGER, 
                   PRIMARY KEY (id, s) on conflict replace, 
                   UNIQUE (name, s));

insert into test values (1, "a", 0);
insert into test values (1, "a", 0);
```

I get "UNIQUE constraint failed" right away. The problem disappears if don't share column between both primary key and unique constraint:

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (id INTEGER, name TEXT,
                   PRIMARY KEY (id) on conflict replace, 
                   UNIQUE (name));

insert into test values (1, "a");
insert into test values (1, "a");
insert into test values (2, "b");
insert into test values (2, "a");
```

Here, I get constraint violation on the very last statement, which is precisely right. Sadly, I do need to share a column between constraints.

Is this something I don't understand about SQL, or SQLite issue, and how do I get the desired effect, except for first trying insert and then doing update on failure?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to apply the ON CONFLICT REPLACE clause to the UNIQUE constraint also?

```
create table test (id INTEGER, name TEXT,
               PRIMARY KEY (id) on conflict replace, 
               UNIQUE (name) on conflict replace);
```

Comment: I think that would be equivalent to my first attempt, since "insert or replace" is basically adding replace behavior on every constraint. When I try this suggestion, along with data from the first example above with just "insert", I get both existing rows replaced.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an embedded database without client/server communication overhead, so it is not necessary to try to do this in a single statement.

To simulate UPSERT, just execute the UPDATE/INSERT statements separately:

```py
c.execute("UPDATE test SET s = ? WHERE id = ? AND name = ?", [0, 1, "a"])
if c.rowcount == 0:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO test(s, id, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [0, 1, "a"])
```

Since SQLite 3.24.0, you can just use [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html).

Comment: That is understood, and this is the code I have now, and it gets the job done. Still, two statements have more overhead than one, and don't make an elegant approach.

Comment: Not an option if you insert with a subselect