# Insert or update with select and override nulls

Tags: sql, sqlite, upsert

I got two tables: **defaults** and **users** with same columns, except in **defaults** the column **user_id** is unique while in "users" it's not.

I want to take all the rows from **users** and insert them to **defaults**, if two rows in users got the same **user_id**, I want to merge them in such way that all the empty/null values will be overridden with non empty/null values

Here is an example

```
users
-----
user_id|name|email|address
--------------------------
1      |abc |null |J St
1      |coco|a@b.c|null
```

After inserting to defaults I expect the next result:

```
defaults
-----
user_id|name|email|address
--------------------------
1      |abc |a@b.c|J St
```

**@Eric B** provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330694/1129332) of how to do this with insert values:

> Assuming 3 columns in the table.. ID, NAME, ROLE
>   This will update 2 of
>   the columns. When ID=1 exists, the ROLE will be unaffected. When ID=1
>   does not exist, the role will be set to 'Benchwarmer' instead of the
>   default value.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Employee (id, name, role) 
  VALUES (  1, 
            'Susan Bar',
            COALESCE((SELECT role FROM Employee WHERE id = 1), 'Benchwarmer')
          );
```

How to do this when I use select for my insert

```
insert or replace into defaults select ??? from users
```

Comment: Which one should be chosen if there is more than one non-NULL value?

Comment: @CL. it doesn't metter for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INT DEFAULTS VALUES (ID, Name, Role)
  (
    SELECT ID, MAX(Name), MAX(Role) FROM Users GROUP BY ID
  );
```

The max will select the max value instead of null if there is one.