# SQLite CASE statement - INSERT IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite database.

I want to insert `id value` or `url Value` if `id Value` not exists, but there is no support of IF() function, how should I write it with SQL CASE statement?

```
require 'sqlite3'
$db.execute("
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from table WHERE id='123456')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sap(id,url) VALUES('123456', 'https:/test.com');
END;")
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to write this as a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO sap(id, url)
    SELECT id, url 
    FROM (SELECT '123456' as id, 'https:/test.com' as url) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sap WHERE sap.id = t.id);
```

However, the correct answer is to use a unique index/constraint so the database does the checking internally:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_sap_id ON sap(id);
```

If you attempt to insert a duplicate value for `id`, the `INSERT` will fail.

Comment: thank you, so I just need to create the index one time, right ?

Comment: @Berlin . . . Yes.  Once you create it the database will maintain it.

Comment: thanks again for your help!