# SQLite: difference between 'INSERT OR REPLACE' and only 'REPLACE'

Tags: sqlite

I've found many discussions about `INSERT OR REPLACE` and I thought it was clear to me, but after reading [this article](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-statement/) saying:

> The following illustrates the syntax of the REPLACE statement.
>
> ```
> INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table(column_list)
> VALUES(value_list);
> ```
>
> Or in a
>   shorter form:
>
> ```
> REPLACE INTO table(column_list)
> VALUES(value_list);
> ```

I'm afraid I missed something.

Why is the `INSERT` statement needed together with `REPLACE`?
Does it actually make any difference in examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330694/5802289), for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, consult the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html) (emphasis mine):

> The REPLACE command is an alias for the "[INSERT OR REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)" variant of the [INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) command. ***This alias is provided for compatibility other SQL database engines.*** See the [INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) command documentation for additional information.