# Insert data in same rows of SQLite database

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have a SQLite database like this below picture where i want to insert value on the same rows of **DAYS** column. for better understanding I've marked red color where I want to insert value but each time new row is created for same DAYS.
How can I achieve this?

[image]

Here is my insertData method where I'm inserting value to row

```
public boolean insertData(String days, String tasbeehName, int count){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_DAYS, days);
    contentValues.put(tasbeehName, count);

    //Long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_TASBEEH_COUNT,null, contentValues);
    Long result = sqLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_TASBEEH_COUNT,null, contentValues,sqLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: You want to update column where date is equal to today

Comment: yes sir! @JibяaᴎKhaᴎ

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you can try

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(COLUMN_DAYS, days);
contentValues.put(tasbeehName, count);

sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_TASBEEH_COUNT, values, "DAYS = date('now')" , null);
sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
```

Comment: try the edit above and let me know if any error occurrs'

Comment: You need to change the date method as per your requirement. I have modified it with respect to your column values

Answer (score 0):

You can first check if a row is already exist with a existing `DAYS` values then you can update the existing row or insert new row.

You can do this in a single query. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330694/1292557). I am pasting here sample query from that answer:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Employee (id, role, name) 
VALUES (  1, 
        'code monkey',
        (SELECT name FROM Employee WHERE id = 1)
      );
```

This will update your given `columns` if a row exist with `id = 1` or insert a new row.