# INSERT ELSE UPDATE a row in a table without primary key

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Lets say i have an empty table *'tbl_test'* with 3 columns and **no primary key**;
  *column1* and *column2* are string, *column3* is int

> And i setup a function ***myFunc(column1Data, column2Data)*** {
>
> // I expect it to be like this
>
> if column1Data **AND** column2Data exists in my table, it will update and
>   increment my column3
>
> else if column1Data **OR** column2Data doesnt exist, it will insert
>   column1Data, column2Data and column3 will set to 0
>
> }

I have tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330694

And this is my code: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cE1FSJawQJFjSHsk93Lrjt/0

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_test (
    column1 varchar(255),
    column2 varchar(255),
    column3 int(12)
);

INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tbl_test (column1, column2, column3) 
  VALUES (  COALESCE((SELECT column1 FROM tbl_test WHERE column1 = 'column1Data'), 'column1Data') ,
            COALESCE((SELECT column2 FROM tbl_test WHERE column2 = 'column2Data'), 'column2Data') ,
            COALESCE((SELECT SUM(column3+1) AS Total FROM tbl_test WHERE column1 = 'column1Data' AND column2 = 'column2Data'), 0)
          );

INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tbl_test (column1, column2, column3) 
  VALUES (  COALESCE((SELECT column1 FROM tbl_test WHERE column1 = 'column1Data'), 'column1Data') ,
            COALESCE((SELECT column2 FROM tbl_test WHERE column2 = 'column2Data'), 'column2Data') ,
            COALESCE((SELECT SUM(column3+1) AS Total FROM tbl_test WHERE column1 = 'column1Data' AND column2 = 'column2Data'), 0)
          );

INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tbl_test (column1, column2, column3) 
  VALUES (  COALESCE((SELECT column1 FROM tbl_test WHERE column1 = 'column1Data'), 'column1Data') ,
            COALESCE((SELECT column2 FROM tbl_test WHERE column2 = 'column2DataNew'), 'column2DataNew') ,
            COALESCE((SELECT SUM(column3+1) AS Total FROM tbl_test WHERE column1 = 'column1Data' AND column2 = 'column2DataNew'), 0)
          );
```

This will insert new data if either column1Data **OR** column2Data doesn't exist and will set column3 = 0 which is correct

But if column1Data **AND** column2Data does exist it will INSERT a new row and increments the column3, instead of updating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite 3.24+, you can use [`upsert`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html).  This starts with a unique constraint on the first two columns:

```
create unique index unq_tbl_test_column1_column2 on tbl_test(column1, column2);
```

Add a default value of 0 for column3 when you create it.

Then you can express what you want as:

```
insert into tbl_test (column1, column2)
    values (?, ?)
    on conflict (column1, column2)
        do update set column3 = column3 + 1;
```