# How to append to existing TEXT row [sqlite3]

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I would like to take an existing `TEXT` field/row and append to it with sqlite3. I'm finding it somewhat difficult, I've seen some stuff with "upsert."

[SQLite - UPSERT *not* INSERT or REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace)

The specific database I'm working with has no relational connections to any other tables.

Assuming the ideal (pseudo code) `UPDATE Table APPEND row values(" text")`

assuming `row` contains `"my "` I would like it to result in `"my text"`

Ideally I would like to do this in a single query, but until then I'm left to selecting and using `update set`

Comment: `UPDATE footable SET bar = bar || 'text' WHERE whatever` doesn't work?

Comment: Woah I didn't think of that, I'll try it. I'll update it afterwards.

Comment: @Shawn Worked, thanks. If you wanna add that as the answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the current values of columns in an update:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET somecol = somecol || 'text' WHERE somecondition;
```

Comment: for anyone wondering like me, || in sqlite is similar to CONCAT in other flavors of SQL, and adds two strings together here.