# Problem with my CSV file insertion and my manual insertion functions

Tags: python, sqlite

i have this project to do a sort of japanese duolingo but not with only language type question (culture, reference, what to do and not to do ect...)

Right now i'm focusing on the language part but to improve the capacity of evolution fo my code, i devided it in more logiccal function in each area of function (main for the main code, affichage (it's display in french) for all the printed message of the code, question for the question functions, and db for all the database function which is coded in SQLite3)

But my function for importing csv files into my database and my manual insertion fuctions doesn't work anymore, i use a function that but a list of all the presnt words in the database to verify my worries, and every time i checked, i don't find the error. Can you help me localise the problem please ?

Here the fraction of the code in main.py :

```
if db_menu_ajouter == '1':
    valeurs = afficher_et_ajouter(valeurs)
    db.ajouter_mot_ou_mettre_a_jour(connexion, valeurs, sqlite3)
    connexion.commit()
elif db_menu_ajouter == '2':
    nom_fichier = afficher_et_ajouter()
    nouveaux_mots, doublons = db.importer_mots_csv(connexion, nom_fichier)
    # affichage.gestion_donnees("import", nouveaux_mots=nouveaux_mots, doublons=doublons)  # Ajouter les paramètres nouveaux_mots et doublons
    connexion.commit()
```

the necessary code in affichage.py :

```
def afficher_et_ajouter():
    choix = input("Choisissez une option :\n1. Ajouter manuellement\n2. Importer depuis un fichier CSV\n")
    
    if choix == '1':
        hiragana = input("Entrez le mot : ")
        français = input("Entrez la réponse : ")
        romaji = input("Entrez la traduction en rōmaji : ")
        kanji = input("Entrez la mot en kanji (si possible et necessaire) :")
        kunyomi = input("Entrez sa lecture kun'yomi :")
        onyomi = input("Entrez sa lecture on'yomi :")
        valeurs = ('1',hiragana, français, romaji, kanji, kunyomi, onyomi)
        return valeurs  # Retourne simplement les valeurs sans indication de choix
    
    elif choix == '2':
        nom_fichier = input("Entrez le nom du fichier CSV à importer : ")
        return (nom_fichier)
    else:
        print("Choix invalide. Veuillez entrer 1 ou 2.")
        return None
    

def gestion_donnees(action, data=None, nouveaux_mots=None, doublons=None):
    if action == "ajout":
        kanji, français, romaji = data
        message = f"Le mot '{kanji}' a été ajouté à la base de données avec la réponse '{français}' ('{romaji}')."
    elif action == "mise_à_jour":
        kanji, français, romaji = data
        message = f"La réponse du mot '{kanji}' a été mise à jour avec la nouvelle réponse '{français}' ('{romaji}')."
    elif action == "import":
        if doublons:
            message = f"{len(doublons)} doublons ont été trouvés dans le fichier CSV."
            supprimer_doublons = input("Voulez-vous supprimer les doublons ? (Oui/Non) : ").strip().lower()
            while True:
                if supprimer_doublons == 'oui':
                    nouveaux_mots = [mot for mot in nouveaux_mots if mot not in doublons]
                    message += f"\n{len(nouveaux_mots)} nouveaux mots ont été importés après suppression des doublons."
                    break
                elif supprimer_doublons == 'non':
                    message += f"\n{len(nouveaux_mots)} nouveaux mots ont été importés sans suppression des doublons."
                    break
                else:
                    message += "\nRéponse Invalide"
        elif nouveaux_mots:
            message = f"{len(nouveaux_mots)} nouveaux mots ont été importés avec succès dans la base de données."
        else:
            message = "Aucun nouveau mot à importer depuis le fichier CSV."
        print(message)
    elif action == "afficher_liste":
        rows = data
        message = "Liste des données dans la base de données :\n"
        for row in rows:
            kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji = row
            message += f"Kanji: {kanji}, Hiragana: {hiragana}, Kun'yomi: {kunyomi}, On'yomi: {onyomi}, Français: {français}, Romaji: {romaji}\n"
    elif action == "vider":
        message = "La base de données a été vidée avec succès."
    else:
        message = "Action non reconnue."

    print(message)

[...]

def mots_not_found():
    print("Il n'y a pas de mots correspondants dans la base de données.")


def gestion_erreur(erreur_type, details=""):
    if erreur_type == "erreur simple":
        print(details)
    if erreur_type == "sqlite":
        print(f"Erreur SQLite : {details}")
    elif erreur_type == "fichier_non_trouve":
        print(f"Le fichier '{details}' n'a pas été trouvé.")
    elif erreur_type == "exception":
        print(f"Une erreur s'est produite : {details}")
```

and the code in db.py :

```
def ajouter_mot_ou_mettre_a_jour(kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji, ajout, mise_à_jour):
    connexion = sqlite3.connect("japan_exercice.db")
    curseur = connexion.cursor()
    
    # Vérifiez si le mot existe déjà dans la base de données
    curseur.execute("SELECT id FROM mots WHERE hiragana = ?", (hiragana,))
    row = curseur.fetchone()
    
    if row is None:
        # Le mot n'existe pas, ajoutez-le à la base de données
        curseur.execute("INSERT INTO mots (kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji))
        affichage.gestion_donnees("ajout")
    else:
        # Le mot existe, mettez à jour sa réponse
        curseur.execute("UPDATE mots SET français = ?, romaji = ?, kunyomi = ?, onyomi = ?, kanji = ?, WHERE hiragana = ?", (kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji))
        affichage.gestion_donnees("mise_à_jour")
    
    # Validez les modifications et fermez la connexion
    connexion.commit()
    connexion.close()


# Nom de la fonction - Usage -----------------------------------------------------------------------
def afficher_liste(connexion, sqlite):
    try:
        curseur = connexion.cursor()
        
        # Sélectionnez toutes les données de la table "mots"
        curseur.execute("SELECT kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji FROM mots")
        rows = curseur.fetchall()
        
        affichage.gestion_donnees("afficher_liste",rows)
    except sqlite3.Error:
        affichage.gestion_erreur(sqlite)


# IMPORTER_MOT_CSV - Import d'un fichier CSV dans la BDD --------------------------------------------------
def importer_mots_csv(connexion, nom_fichier):
    try:
        with open(nom_fichier, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fichier_csv:
            contenu_csv = list(csv.reader(fichier_csv))
            print(f"Contenu du fichier CSV : {contenu_csv}")

            lecteur_csv = csv.DictReader(fichier_csv, fieldnames=["Kanji", "Hiragana", "Kun'yomi", "On'yomi", "Français", "Romaji"])
            nouveaux_mots = []

            for ligne in lecteur_csv:
                kanji = ligne.get("Kanji", "")
                hiragana = ligne.get("Hiragana", "")
                kunyomi = ligne.get("Kun'yomi", "")
                onyomi = ligne.get("On'yomi","")
                français = ligne.get("Français", "")
                romaji = ligne.get("Romaji", "")

                # Vérifier si le mot est déjà présent dans la base de données
                cur = connexion.cursor()
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mots WHERE kanji=? AND hiragana=? AND kunyomi=? AND onyomi=? AND français=? AND romaji=?", (kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji))
                resultat = cur.fetchone()

                if resultat is None:
                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO mots (kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji))
                    nouveaux_mots.append({"kanji": kanji, "hiragana": hiragana, "français": français, "Kun'yomi": kunyomi, "On'yomi": onyomi, "romaji": romaji})
            connexion.commit()

            if len(nouveaux_mots) > 0:
                message = f"{len(nouveaux_mots)} nouveaux mots ont été importés avec succès dans la base de données."
            else:
                message = "Aucun nouveau mot à importer depuis le fichier CSV."
            print(message)
    except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Le fichier CSV n'a pas été trouvé.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'importation du fichier CSV : {str(e)}")
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
def get_mots(connexion, columns, number_lines, sqlite):
    curseur = connexion.cursor()
    try:
        columns_names = ",".join(columns)
        curseur.execute(f"SELECT {columns_names} FROM mots ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT {number_lines}")
        if number_lines == 1:
            row = curseur.fetchone()
            if row:
               return row 
            else: return False
    except sqlite3.Error:
        affichage.gestion_erreur(sqlite)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
def ajouter_mots(connexion, mots, sqlite):
    try:
        curseur = connexion.cursor()
        
        for mot in mots:
            kanji = mot.get("kanji", "")
            hiragana = mot.get("hiragana", "")
            kunyomi = mot.get("Kun'yomi", "")
            onyomi = mot.get("On'yomi", "")
            français = mot.get("français", "")
            romaji = mot.get("romaji", "")

            curseur.execute("INSERT INTO mots (kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji))

        # Validez les modifications
        connexion.commit()
        affichage.gestion_donnees("ajout", (kanji, hiragana, kunyomi, onyomi, français, romaji))
    except sqlite3.Error:
        affichage.gestion_erreur(sqlite)
```

to see where is the problem i tried to put temporary print in the function importer_mots_csv to see if the problem came from here but nothing came out (even the print in gestion_code) same thing happend with manual  insertion so i think that one of the problem came from here because my function afficher_et_ajouter works perfectly.

Comment: In the `UPDATE` query you have an extra `,` before `WHERE`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/upsert-not-insert-or-replace for how you can do `INSERT OR UPDATE` in a single query.

Comment: `lecteur_csv` will not read anything. You already read the entire file when you did `contenu_csv = list(csv.reader(fichier_csv))` so there's nothing left for `lecteur_csv` to read.

Comment: Put `fichier_csv.seek(0)` before creating `lecteur_csv` to go back to the beginning of the file. Or just get rid of `contenu_csv` because you don't use it.

Comment: ok i see now thanks !