# How insert only distinct rows based on data in output/blob storage using azure stream analytics?

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm trying to store only distinct rows in my output- Blob storage based on old data in that output-blob storage using azure stream analytics query language.
Eg:
On the first insert, I get some values to the streaming analytics input as below

```
Name, Score
saran, 100
raj,   90
```

and the above data is stored in blob as output.

On the second insert, I get the following table from stream analytics input

```
Name, Score
saran, 90
jeeva, 80
```

Now before storing this data to the blob, I have to compare the old data from 
a blob with new data and to insert only the distinct data to the blob and also I wanna update the value for already existing data.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Your main requirement is implementing `Upsert` feature in the ASA blob storage output,and as i know , you can't get that feature in blob storage output.

However,you could consider loading the data into below output before blob storage(final destination) as workarounds:

1.Azure Cosmos DB SQL API:

Stream Analytics integration with Azure Cosmos DB allows you to insert or update records in your container based on a given Document ID column.More details,please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-documentdb-output#upserts-from-stream-analytics).

2.SQL Database:

You could use stored procedure in the sql database to implement upsert,please refer to this thread:[How to implement a conditional Upsert stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106717/how-to-implement-a-conditional-upsert-stored-procedure)

After above process, you could load data into blob storage.For example,using [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) in ADF.

Comment: Thank you, How can I do the same in the question that I have asked, If I use Power BI as Output.

Comment: @saranrajkumar All i know about upsert in ASA are listed in my answer.  You could connect PB to Azure Blob Storage:http://georgevwoods.com/2019/01/26/connect-settings-to-use-azure-blob-storage-as-a-data-source-for-the-power-bi-service/

Comment: @saranrajkumar So,any updates?Does my answer helps you?