# Stop Inserting in Table if record already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, try-catch

I have sql server procedure, please see below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertDelegate]
(
    @CourseID int,
    @CPUserID int,
    @StatusID int,
    @CreateUser varchar(25)

)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
INSERT INTO tblDelegate                      
(
    CourseID, 
    CPUserID, 
    StatusID, 
    CreateUser 

)
VALUES     
(
    @CourseID,
    @CPUserID,
    @StatusID,
    @CreateUser
)

RETURN
```

Now I don't want to insert into table **tblDelegate** if the inserting **courseid** and **cpuserid** is same for that records in table tblDelegate

Comment: are you trying to upsert? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540/insert-update-stored-proc-on-sql-server

Comment: @Sam: it looks more like an insert if not exists problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply test first. In SQL Server 2005 you could also  TRY/CATCH to ignore a duplicate error.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM tblDelegate
        WHERE CourseID = @CourseID etc)
    INSERT INTO tblDelegate                      
    (
        CourseID, 
        CPUserID, 
        StatusID, 
        CreateUser 

    )
    VALUES     
    (
        @CourseID,
        @CPUserID,
        @StatusID,
        @CreateUser
    )
```

May I ask: do you mean "SET NOCOUNT ON"?

Comment: this is not safe for concurrency, with heavy concurrency you will get dupes.

Comment: Always worth adding the unique key constraint too and using an appropriate locking level.

Comment: @Sam: True, seen it happen, but it's OK for a lot of situations. @pjp: The PK would normally be the unique constraint

Answer (score 3):

Add a **unique key** constraint to the `courseid` and `cpuuserid` columns.

You'll then get a key violation if you try to insert a dupe.

As well as doing this you can test to see if the value exists before inserting it using your stored procedure.

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT 1 
FROM tblDelegate WITH (TABLOCK) 
WHERE CourseId=@CourseID 
      AND CPUserID=@CPUserId
IF @@rowcount = 0
BEGIN
--Record doesn't already exist
--Insert it
END

COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQL Server you are using ? If you are on 2008 look up the MERGE statement.

Use the IF NOT Exists Clause then as pointed in the first answer.