# included columns for a non-clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

Hello
i have a table with lots of records(11 million). The records has a foreign ID, Date and some other fields.
I have a query which i run in my application so often. The query is something like:

```
if( SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Date=@Date AND ForeignID=@ForeignID != 0 )    
     UPDATE myTable SET ....... WHERE Date=@Date AND ForeignID=@ForeignID
else
     INSERT INTO myTable(......) VALUES(.....)
```

I want to add "Date" as a nonclustered index. Then if i add "ForeignID" column as included column for that index, will it help the query executes faster?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @gbn that you need an index on both Date and ForeignID rather than "Include Column".

You could create it as follows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX1] ON [myTable] ([Date], [ForeignID])
```

However "Select * " is not a good way to check the existence of a record. You could use the "EXISTS" clause

Answer (score 1):

Adding `ForeignID` will help as index will cover the subquery and it will not need to grab `ForeignID` from the table.

However, it is better to add unique constraint or index for both `Date` and `ForeignID`.

Like this:

```
create unique index IX_MyTable_Date_ForeignID on MyTable(Date, ForeignID)
```

Also, you might want to use `MERGE` statement for this kind of query. Depends on what SQL version you use.

Comment: I use both Sql Server 2005/2008. I will search for MERGE thanks. You think adding nonclustered indexes for both Date and ForeignID seperatly is better?

Comment: @Fer - Not separately, one index for both fields. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need an index on both Date and ForeignID, with Date first. It is a filter (in the WHERE clause) so it should be in the key columns not the INCLUDE columns

Also, your pattern of test..update..else..insert isn't scalable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:27535%20JFDI) for other ways of doing it: [Select / Insert version of an Upsert: is there a design pattern for high concurrency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593870/select-insert-version-of-an-upsert-is-there-a-design-pattern-for-high-concurre/3594328#3594328)

Comment: should i add Date and ForeignID seperatly as indexes? I will search for a better pattern about checking updating-inserting. Thnks.

Comment: @Fer: no, a composite index on both columns. (Update: as per Hasan's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I would expect it to speed up this query significantly (do you need to do a select * ?)

but it would slow down inserts into the table as it has another index to write - it will obviously increase the size of the db as well.

It's probably worth adding if this often run proc is really slow.

Comment: I think i must be added too. But i am searching for the best way to add an index. By the way i need select for testing of exsiting record but i may use any other method to do that.