# Update or Insert Depending on Whether the Record Already Exists

Tags: sql-server

I want to update "Grade" Column in "StudentTable" with a WHERE clause of "StudentID"". And if there is no "StudentID" found in "StudentTable" then I want to Insert the data instead.

How can I do this?

Comment: You wanna do this in plane SQL or do you have some kind of programming language ?

Comment: Please tag/specify the version of SQL Server you are using - this information is *always* useful to include in your question. There are "safer" methods to achieve this but they are not necessarily valid if you're on an older version of SQL Server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Atomic UPSERT in SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522379/atomic-upsert-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first check if the record exists, if it does perform an update,
if it does not exist, it means you will need to insert it.

Here you go:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM StudentTable WHERE StudentID = @MyID)
  BEGIN 
    --exists perform update
    UPDATE StudentTable SET Grade = 'A+' WHERE StudentID=@MyID
    --other code...
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    --record does not exist INSERT it
     INSERT INTO StudentTable(MyID, Grade) VALUES (@MyID, 'A+')
    --other code...
  END
```

Comment: In T-SQL, the comment specifier is --, not apostrophe.  And the BEGIN/END stuff isn't necessary here.  But +1 cuz it's a good answer.

Comment: @hoodaticus - sorry working on a vb.net app at the moment and comments in vb.net are '.  Sorry, and the begin / end are not needed if no other statements exist, he / she may have other code so they can determine whether to leave the begin / end statements.

Comment: I thought it was VB leakage :)

Comment: This won't scale because 2 processes overlapping could see "NOT EXIST" and try to INSERT. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/only-inserting-a-row-if-its-not-already-there/3408196#3408196 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593870/select-insert-version-of-an-upsert-is-there-a-design-pattern-for-high-concurre/3594328#3594328 for how to do it. For why, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709935/how-sql-server-handles-concurrent-requests/6709958#6709958

Comment: Thanks JonH, Will the above solution work if I have two rows for a StudendID: "JD1212" and want to update the two and Insert One for the Same Student?

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1704

MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Note that MERGE is new as of SQL Server 2008. It won't work in older versions.

Comment: good point. For best backwards compatibility, you're best with a solution like what @JonH gave...

Comment: Wow -- I didn't know about merge -- that's cool.  Backward compatibility???  Whatchutalkinbout Willis?