# Insert data and if already inserted then update in sql

Tags: java, sql

I simply want to insert the data to a SQL database table and if there is some data inserted already then I want to update that data. How can I do this using Java. Kindly help me, and sorry for bad English in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upsert (update and insert) in SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010511/how-to-upsert-update-and-insert-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Which database? SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? DB2? Oracle?

Comment: Are you using any ORM framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just identify the **unique item** in your data set (like **Id** or a **code**). Then by using that try to do a **SELECT** query first. If the **Resultset** is empty, do the **INSERT** else try to **UPDATE** the details.

Answer (score 7):

The standard SQL statement for `INSERT` (if new) or `UPDATE` (if exists) is called **`MERGE`**.

Since you didn't specify which DBMS dialect you're asking about, I'll refer you to the Wikipedia article "[Merge (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29)", which covers most DBMS dialects. Summary:

> ```
> MERGE INTO tablename USING table_reference ON (condition)
> WHEN MATCHED THEN
>   UPDATE SET column1 = value1 [, column2 = value2 ...]
> WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
>   INSERT (column1 [, column2 ...]) VALUES (value1 [, value2 ...])
> ```
>
> Database management systems *Oracle Database*, *DB2*, *Teradata*, *EXASOL*, *CUBRID*, *MS SQL* and *Vectorwise* support the standard syntax. Some also add non-standard SQL extensions.
>
> *MySQL*: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
>
> *SQLite*: `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO`
>
> *PostgreSQL*: `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT`

Comment: The question was related to Java (JDBC.HSQL, or other ORM).

Comment: @EddyBayonne Yes, and you can run those SQL statements from Java too. Nothing in the question says ORM, so running SQL using JDBC is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: We should prefer strategy which finishes the job in one connection and statement. Above answer soots best to avoid multiple connection openings and performance impact in batch.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) keyword to check for the existance of rows:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM...)
BEGIN
    UPDATE....
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT...
END
```

Comment: It's more efficient to just run the update and check how many rows were updated.

Answer (score 2):

you have to first check the data exist in table
if exist then use update query otherwise insert data
its simple

Answer (score 2):

try to following way:

**Example Query**

INSERT INTO table (id, name, city) VALUES(1, "ABC", "XYZ") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
name="ABC", city="XYZ"

for more help see documentation.
[Click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Set any field as the unique identity.**
For an example consider that employee details has to be entered in the table name **EmployeeDetails.**in this case employee_id can be considered as unique.

use **SELECT** query
select * from EmployeeDetails where employee_id= "the unique keyvalue";
if the resultset is not empty then use **UPDATE** query to update the fields.

update EmployeeDetails set Employee_id=?,Full_name=?, Designation=?, Email_id=?, Password=? where Employee_id='"
                        + id + "'";
If the resultset is empty then use the INSERT query to insert the values to the table

Insert into EmployeeDetails values(...)

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.stackwork;

//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Updation {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Employee";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "admin";
   private static Scanner sc;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      //STEP 5: Get the employee_id for whom data need to be updated/inserted
      sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the Employee_id for the record to be updated or inserted");
      int Emp_idvalue=sc.nextInt();
      sql = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails where Emp_id="+Emp_idvalue;
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      if (!rs.next())
      {
          //STEP 6: If the previous details is not there ,then the details will be inserted newly
          System.out.println("Enter the name to be inserted");
          String Emp_namevalue =sc.next();
          System.out.println("Enter the address to be inserted");
          String Emp_addvalue =sc.next();
          System.out.println("Enter the role to be inserted");
          String Emp_rolevalue =sc.next();
          PreparedStatement ps = conn
                    .prepareStatement("insert into EmployeeDetails values(?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(2, Emp_namevalue);
            ps.setString(3, Emp_addvalue);
            ps.setString(4, Emp_rolevalue);
            ps.setInt(1, Emp_idvalue);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Inserted successfully");
      }
      else
      {
        //STEP 7: If the previous details is  there ,then the details will be updated 
          System.out.println("Enter the name to be updated");
          String Emp_namevalue =sc.next();
          System.out.println("Enter the address to be updated");
          String Emp_addvalue =sc.next();
          System.out.println("Enter the role to be updated");
          String Emp_rolevalue =sc.next();
          String updateQuery = "update EmployeeDetails set Emp_id=?,Emp_name=?, Emp_address=?, Emp_role=? where Emp_id='"
                    + Emp_idvalue + "'";
            PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
            ps1.setString(2, Emp_namevalue);
            ps1.setString(3, Emp_addvalue);
            ps1.setString(4, Emp_rolevalue);
            ps1.setInt(1, Emp_idvalue);
            ps1.executeUpdate();    
            System.out.println("updated successfully");

      }
      //Clean-up environment
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();

   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
}
```