# How to fix error jdbc4 duplicate entry when update/insert

Tags: java, jdbc

When I update or insert in jbdc4 I got this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry '0006-0208-254-3491-254254-01774' for key 'PRIMARY'
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)

Any solution?

Comment: Solution is to not use the same primary key value twice.

Comment: can show for the example, please.?? thank you

Comment: What example? Just don't insert the same primary key twice.

Comment: that's just one same primary bro

Comment: if you try add same primary key, you will end up wiht this error, Primary key is Unique entry, consider update instead of insert  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442307/insert-data-and-if-already-inserted-then-update-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

This error message tells you that you are trying to insert an entry in the database that has a primary key value equal to one of a previously inserted entry. This is the function of a primary key, is to be able to uniquely identify an entry, and prevent duplicate values of the field that is selected to be a primary key.

Example: If you have a table with the following columns("id","age"). If you choose "id" to be the primary key, then you cannot insert the following entries:

*insert (1,20)

*insert (1,25) -->Here it will give you the above mentioned error in your question.

Instead, you can insert the following:

*insert (1,20)

*insert (2,25) or insert (2,20)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the check **[Skip Tests]** checkbox can be helpful.

You can find it through `Settings---Build, Execution, Deployment---Build Tools---Maven---Runner`(Intellij IDEA).

Answer (score -2):

This happens on an update statement which has nothing to do with the Primary Key I believe. Kinda messy situation. When you execute the same SQL statements on sql prompt, it gives perfect result and if you add a delay to the same program and run it again it might work too. Think its something to do with the JDBC mysql connection when you run a considerable load at a stretch.