# Is it possible to update primary key (HBase)?

Tags: mysql, sql, hbase, apache-phoenix

Is it possible to update field which is not null in phoenix HBase ?

For example in table with fields `id` (not null ), `name` (not null) and `number`.

When I write query

```
Upsert into table t_table (id,name,number) values (1,name1,2);
```

If I have record with `id  = 1` and `name = name`, when I execute this query it will create another record in database with same `id = 1`, `name = name1` and `number = 2`.

Is there any way to just update this field name without duplicating data?

Comment: a `PRIMARY KEY` should not be updated gets you in trouble when you use relations between other tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upsert (update or insert) in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010511/how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: You are (somehow) asking 3 different unrelated things in the same question - please be more precise.