# VBA - Running an Insert Statement is returning rowsAffected = 1 but isn't actually inserting any rows into table. Statement works fine in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba

**Problem:** Insert statements run through VBA are returning `rowsAffected = 1`, however when a select statement is run on that table, it does not show any new rows. Running the exact same insert statement through SQL Server works as intended, so I know it isn't the statement itself that is the issue.

I have created a spreadsheet in which my colleagues can input some data into columns and my VBA will determine what data needs to be updated into our server. I am having trouble with `INSERT` statements, however my `UPDATE` statements are working just fine.

Below is the code I am running. It runs an `UPDATE` query first, and if `rowsAffected` returns 0, then it instead grabs the corresponding `INSERT` statement and attempts to run that. Prior to this subroutine running, I have another sub that creates all the `UPDATE` queries and all of the `INSERT` queries and stores them in collections which are passed to the below subroutine.

```
Private Sub sqlQueryNotes(queries As Collection, iQueries As Collection)
    'queries collection stores all of the UPDATE queries
    'iQueries collection stores all of the INSERT queries    

Dim rAffected As Integer
Dim cn As Adodb.Connection
Set cn = New Adodb.Connection

Dim cString As String
    cString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;" & _
                       "Server=[SERVERNAME];" & _
                       "Database=[DATABASENAME];" & _
                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;"

cn.connectionString = cString
cn.Open

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To queries.Count

    cn.Execute "Begin Tran " & queries.Item(i), rAffected 'UPDATE statement
    
    If rAffected = 0 Then
                       
            'below code looks a bit messy but it works, it finds the contractID from the update query and uses that as a key for the insertQuery key to find the corresponding insert query. It could be done better, but it works
            cn.Execute "Begin Tran " & iQueries.Item(getContractID(queries.Item(i))), rAffected 
            
            If rAffected > 1 Then
                cn.Execute "Rollback"
                GoTo NextQuery
            ElseIf rAffected = 0 Then
                GoTo NextQuery
            Else
                cn.Execute "Commit"
                GoTo NextQuery
            End If
        
    ElseIf rAffected = 1 Then
        
        cn.Execute "Commit "
    
    End If
    
NextQuery:
Next i

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have tested this dozens of times, each time individually stepping through each line and checking the `rowsAffected` variable manually confirming that it has in fact inserted the data I want (by returning the value 1). This code DOES work exactly the way as intended, and I do in fact get `rowsAffected = 1` when I run the `INSERT` statements.

**However**, when I run a `SELECT` statement for the table it is inserting into, it returns no new rows!

I have taken the `INSERT` statements generated with my VBA code and have run them through SQL Server and they work fine. So why won't it work through my VBA code?

In case it is relevant, below is the code I run to generate the `UPDATE` statements and the `INSERT` statements. I have removed quite a few irrelevant lines for the sake of brevity

```
Sub UpdateBackendDatabase()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim updNoteCol As Integer: updNoteCol = Range("_" & Replace(Left(ws.Name, 6), " ", vbNullString) & "_uNotes").Column
    Dim refNoteCol As Integer: refNoteCol = updNoteCol - 1
    
    Dim contractIdCol As Integer: contractIdCol = Range("_" & Replace(Left(ws.Name, 6), " ", vbNullString) & "_contractId").Column
    Dim contractID As String
    
    Dim tbl As Range
    Set tbl = ws.Range("tblReporting_" & Replace(Left(ws.Name, 6), " ", vbNullString))
    
    Dim notesQueriesColl As New Collection
    Dim insCollection As New Collection
    
    Dim updateQry As String
    Dim insertQry As String

    'Loop through all rows in table and find values that have been updates and add them to a query and add the queries to a collection of queries.
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 3 To Range("tblReporting_" & Replace(Left(ws.Name, 6), " ", vbNullString)).Rows.Count + 2
    
        contractID = tbl.Cells(i, contractIdCol).Value
       
        '===============
        '==== NOTES ====
        '===============
        If tbl.Cells(i, updNoteCol).Value <> vbNullString Then
                'grabs notes from the refNoteCol and concats it with new additional notes from the updNotesCol
            updateQry = "Update tblCMNotes " & _
                            "Set strNotes = '" & tbl.Cells(i, refNoteCol) & "; " & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & tbl.Cells(i, updNoteCol).Value & "' " & _
                            "Where fkidContract = " & CStr(contractID)
            
            insertQry = "Insert Into tblCMNotes " & _
                        "(fkidContract, strNotes) " & _
                        "Values " & _
                        "(" & contractID & ", '" & tbl.Cells(i, refNoteCol) & "; " & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & tbl.Cells(i, updNoteCol).Value & "') "
            
            notesQueriesColl.Add updateQry
            insCollection.Add insertQry, getContractID(updateQry)

        End If
            
    Next i
    
    Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thank you very much for looking into this question.

Comment: I'm not a SQL server user, but aren't you beginning two transactions per loop iteration (if first rAffected = 0), and not closing them both?

Comment: Might be simpler to combine the update/insert commands like Evgeny shows here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15396779/478884

Comment: The provider-specific command text "Commit" or "Commit " are SQL server commands. You probably should be using the ADODB method committrans

Answer (score 0):

The provider-specific command text "Commit" or "Commit " are SQL server commands. You probably should be using the ADODB method committran