# What are some patterns for DB table schemas?

Tags: database-design

I know some patterns to DB table schema:

- one-one: same table.
- one-many: Having 'many' table's primary key a member of 'one' table.
- many-many: Having a new relationship table contains both table's primary key.

What are some other patterns?

Comment: The question is "what is the question?"  It's all very meta.

Comment: @Pesto: Should we add the meta tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about?:

- [Relational Database Design Patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145689/relational-database-design-patterns)
- [Table design patterns](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/01/table-design-patterns.html)
- [Anti-patterns](http://www.pgcon.org/2008/schedule/events/97.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider those 'patterns' since the term patterns are used for more or less complex problem solutions in a given technology, including some notion on the circumstances in which one pattern in superior to another applicable pattern.

The examples you are giving are more the very basic building blocks of relational database schema design. If you want to learn more about this I suggest search for 'database normalization'.

Some terms that could be considered patterns in the database world are:

star schema
snowflake schema
Entity-attribute-value model