# Database Cell with multiple values?

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm

I am designing an app where I want to search for diseases based on symptoms. I am trying to design the database using MySql, but as a beginner I run into some trouble with the design philosophy.

Basically a disease is going to have multiple symptoms, so on the `disease` table I wanted to have these columns:

```
disease_id, disease_name, disease_description, **disease_symptoms**
```

The thing is, one disease is not going to have only a single symptom, and putting multiple values in a single cell goes against DB design philosophy from what I found out online.

So the best solution I found so far was to make a table with multiple columns, 1 for disease id and then like 10 columns called: `symptom_0`, `symptom_1`, `symptom_2`, ect. So when I do a SQL query it can return all the diseases that have a specific symptom.

I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have M-to-N relation between diseases and symptoms (or any other entities, actually), you need 3 tables: first for diseases, like (disease_id, ...), second for symptoms (symptom_id, ...) and the third one, linking table, (disease_id, symptom_id).

Then, you executing SQL like: `SELECT * FROM diseases WHERE disease_id IN (SELECT disease_id FROM diseases_vs_symptoms WHERE symptom_id = MY_SYMPTOM);`

**UPDATE** I've just googled a bit and found this promisingly looking SO question, which you may find useful: [Relational Database Design Patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145689/relational-database-design-patterns)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to create multiple columns, since there are a lot of possible symptoms. The way i'd do it:
Create table `symptoms` with `id` and `name`
Create table `disease_symptoms` with `disease_id` and `symptom_id`

Now, in table `disease_symptoms` you've linked diseases and symptoms, and can easily find which diseases have some symptoms and the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I would create two more tables.
One just for symptoms with two fields: symptom_id and symptom_name.
Second, connecting your diseases with symptoms, two fields: disease_id and symptom_id.
Second table will have as many entries as there is symptoms for that disease.