# JOIN query problems with 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

First and foremost, I don't even know how that query is called, but I bet it exists.

I got a table with events, and numbers representing the (fix)persons, whose are going to go to that event. Okay, then I got an user table, where these persons are, with the id-s from events. So events cell looks like "1,5,22,47", the person id-s.

The question is, how am I supposed to echo the event, with every persons name? :O Some like that:

> "Event: Class trip with: Edward, Dr. Simons, Mrs. Walker"

Without having 315345345 queries...

Table examples:

> Event:
>
> - id, name, date, people
>
> Users:
>
> - id, name
>
> so like:  Event:
>
> - "1", "Class trip", "May 2", "1,2,5,6"
> - "2", "Museum visit", "May 14",    "5,6,8,1"
>
> Users:
>
> - "1", "Edward"
> - "2", "Dr. Simons"

Comment: Can you give a few sample rows from each table?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would NOT recommend storing the relationship between an event and a list of attendees into a single column. This is very bad practice.

Instead, I would use a third table that mapped the relationship between events and attendees. In other words, create a One-to-Many relationship (master-detail, parent-child) using a foreign key.

[Check out this post for more information regarding database design patterns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145689/relational-database-design-patterns)

With a One-to-Many table, you could write a simple SQL query to get the data you want. Something like:

```
SELECT Attendee FROM Event_Attendees WHERE Event LIKE $eventName
```

This would return an array of all the attendees for a particular event. Of course, you would want to use prepared statements using mysqli or PDO.

This `Event_Attendees` table would basically have two primary columns to establish the relationship: `Event` and `Attendee`. I generally use an auto-increment integer as a primary key index.

Comment: Yes it does really work like that, I don't know why I didn't think on that... Probably I was trying to save too much space :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a third table UsersEvents (or something like that):

> - event_id
> - user_id,

Then add rows:

> - 1, 1
> - 1, 2
> - 1, 5
> - 1, 6

and

> - 2, 5
> - 2, 6
> - 2, 8
> - 2, 1

etc

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a function that you call for each row which concatenates all the names into one string and you execute like so

select EventId, EventName, udf_getPeople(EventId) FROM Event

Inside udf_getPeople

declare @everyone varchar(max);

Create a cursor to get the people sequentially related to EventId

fetch for each row

concatenate person fields to @everyone

close cursor when last person encountered

return everyone