# Is MERGE an atomic statement in SQL2008?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, upsert

I am using a `MERGE` statement as an `UPSERT` to either add a new record or update the current one. I have multiple threads driving the database through multiple connections and multiple statements (one connection and statement per thread). I am batching the statements 50 at a time.

I was very surprised to get a `duplicate key` violation during my tests. I expected that to be impossible because the `MERGE` will be performed as a single transaction, or is it?

My Java code looks like:

```
private void addBatch(Columns columns) throws SQLException {
  try {
    // Set parameters.
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
      Column c = columns.get(i);
      // Column type is an `enum` with a `set` method appropriate to its type, e.g. setLong, setString etc.
      c.getColumnType().set(statement, i + 1, c.getValue());
    }
    // Add the insert as a batch.
    statement.addBatch();
    // Ready to execute?
    if (++batched >= MaxBatched) {
      statement.executeBatch();
      batched = 0;
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    log.warning("addBatch failed " + sql + " thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName(), e);
    throw e;
  }
}
```

The query looks like this:

```
MERGE INTO CustomerSpend AS T 
USING ( SELECT ? AS ID, ? AS NetValue, ? AS VoidValue ) AS V 
ON T.ID = V.ID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET T.ID = V.ID, T.NetValue = T.NetValue + V.NetValue, T.VoidValue = T.VoidValue + V.VoidValue 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ( ID,NetValue,VoidValue ) VALUES ( V.ID, V.NetValue, V.VoidValue );
```

The error reads:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CustomerSpend'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CustomerSpend'. The duplicate key value is (498288              ).
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:944)
at x.db.Db$BatchedStatement.addBatch(Db.java:299)
...
```

The key on the table is a `PRIMARY` key on the `ID` field.

Comment: How are you generating the primary key (V.ID)?

Comment: @Paolo `ALTER TABLE CustomerSpend ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerSpend] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the actual value of the ID you were passing in the query.  Mikael's got it below - the transaction is atomic, but there's nothing to stop multiple threads trying to insert the same key

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`MERGE` is atomic meaning that either all changes are committed or all changes are rolled back.

It does not prevent duplicate keys in case of high concurrency. Adding `holdlock` hint will take care of that.

```
MERGE INTO CustomerSpend WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS T 
USING ( SELECT ? AS ID, ? AS NetValue, ? AS VoidValue ) AS V 
ON T.ID = V.ID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET T.ID = V.ID, T.NetValue = T.NetValue + V.NetValue, T.VoidValue = T.VoidValue + V.VoidValue 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ( ID,NetValue,VoidValue ) VALUES ( V.ID, V.NetValue, V.VoidValue );
```

Comment: Can you please tell us when is the meaning of "*in case of high concurrency*" ?

Comment: @abcdefghi [Simultaneous executions of the merge statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)).

Comment: More info about the parallelism risks: [www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) (and a *few* other issues with `MERGE` in T-SQL).