# Multithreading Logical Situation

Tags: java, multithreading

```
S1: Lookup for some input data
S2:  IF not found SET IT
S3:  INSERT DATA
S4:  ELSE RETURN
```

Intially there is no data stored.
If 2 threads simultaneously look up for same input data, lookup returns FALSE in both cases .Then both go through long SET phase. Finally a singleton service Thread Inserts entry in a non synchronized Insert method.

In this way, though lookup was intended to never let same data go twice , because of 2 threads working on same data, its purpose was not solved. HOw to handle such situation in multi threaded programs ?

Comment: depends on how much work youre willing to put into this. easiest solution would be to synchronize on some final static lock Object if the lookup is empty and then, after checking again, do the whole insertion inside the sync block. its called double check locking - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: Using Double_checked_locking with a final static Object , I found two instances of same class stopped for each other. So, this should solve it.

Comment: @radai, Should I have multiple static final lock objects because I don't want differnt methods to lock each other if all are using same Object as lock.

Comment: @fortm - this is where it depends on the amount of effort you want to put in - using a single lock is easiest, but then processes that care about sifferent keys will block each other. using a map of locks by key will allow more threads to run at the same time but is more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check locking applied:

```
S1: Lookup for some input data
S2:  IF not found {
       synchronized(getClass()) {
S2-1:    Lookup for some input data
S2-2:    IF not found
S2-3:    INSERT DATA
       }
S3:  RETURN result of S1, S2-1, or S2-3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with databases then the keyword you alre looking for is [upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9871644/823393).

If ordinary coding, you may be in need of [atomics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) or perhaps [synchronization](http://onjava.com/onjava/excerpt/jthreads3_ch6/index1.html).

If you could clarify your question perhaps we could help further.

Comment: it is database in my case. And in lookup there is a select query and the Insert class is a Singleton DAO . The condition check happens from a class which extends THread and there are different instances of it runing at any time.. SO chances are there , same data may come for each and at same time.

Comment: UPSERT is also a good alternative. thanks for suggesting this. I need to explore how to write such a statement using Spring JDBC for Oracle. So far, it was a plain INSERT