# merge statement duplicate key bug

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I thought MERGE was an atomic insert/update operation, but running a test with multiple threads calling my sproc doing upsert I am running into duplicate key constraint violation, the sproc is not all that difficult

```
-- @someVal, @val1, @val2, @val3 are params passed to my sproc
-- nothing fancy going on there (with the params)
-- where MyVal is a unique non-clustered index
MERGE dbo.MyTable T
USING (@someVal [SomeVal]) S
    ON T.MyVal = S.SomeVal
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET A = @val1
        ,B = @val2
        ,C = @val3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (MyVal, A, B, C)
    VALUES (@someVal, @val1, @val2, @val3)
```

Yet I get the following exception, the only way to get around this has been to either remove the unique index, or add a retry into the sproc.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert
>   duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MyTable' with unique index
>   'UIX_MyUniqueConstraint'. The duplicate key value is
>   (03414D0B-15D2-4AFA-BB7F-7359BB95668A).

When testing without the unique index, I ran a dupe check which turned nothing, confirming the upsert did what it was supposed to and no dupes were actually inserted

```
SELECT MyVal, COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.MyTable
GROUP BY MyVal
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Is this a known bug in SQL Server 2008 R2 and prior versions, or am I doing something wrong?

I found this [connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/434632/cannot-insert-duplicate-key-row-in-object-xxx-with-unique-index-yyy) which is very similar to my issue and it appears they fixed it in SQL Server 2012 but not in prior version

Comment: Sounds to me that your UIX_MyUniqueConstraint index and the primary key are two different columns.  Which one is the merge statement using in the join.  The column(s) identified in the uniqueconstraint or the column defined by the primarykey.  It appears you are joining on the PK but failing on the unique key.

Comment: Why don't you post the definition for the UIX_MyUniqueConstraint?

Comment: Also, you need to specify [@val1], [@val2], [@val3] in your source statement, not just the join value.

Comment: Also you will want to trace through to ensure that the sproc isn't being called twice in succession.

Comment: @RThomas Yes my PK and my UIX are are different columns, the PK is an identity column so no need to touch, the UIX is what I need to drive by (don't ask me why, not my table design, I would've made the UIX my PK and dumped the identity).  I don't understand what you mean by specify [@val1], [@val2], and [@val3] in my source?

Comment: @ChrisLively the UIX is a simple unique index constraint on a single column, I assure you there's nothing fancy going on there :)  also, what do you mean by making sure the sproc isn't being called twice in succession?  the sproc is called once only, but my tester app randomly picks from a predefined set of keys [@someVal], it's multi-threaded to simmulate multiple calls with differing and matching keys to make sure the upsert works correctly

Comment: weird problem. would a hint with tablock or tablockx help? or would that slow down to much? have no idea what causes this, just guessing its conflicting inserts. trying to enforce separation. just a workaround...  edit: spellcheck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is MERGE an atomic statement in SQL2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871644/is-merge-an-atomic-statement-in-sql2008)

Answer (score 3):

After reviewing the comments your problem is the multithreaded test app.  In short, the behavior you describe is expected.

You state that you are randomly picking from a predefined set of keys (someval).  It's highly likely that two different threads are *sometimes* selecting the same someval to run at the same time.  That value does not exist in the target table, so thread 1 and thread 2 attempt to insert it.  The first thread finishes first and the second throws the error because someval now exists.

See the answer here: [Is MERGE an atomic statement in SQL2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871644/is-merge-an-atomic-statement-in-sql2008)

more information about this here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx

Essentially you need to change your MERGE statement to include the HOLDLOCK statement.  This will force each merge task to hold and lock the table during the entirety of it's update/insert.

`MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS T`
...

Finally, the bug you linked to is actually not related to this.

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct, I also state in my question that I removed the unique constraint, ran several tests multi-threaded millions of iterations, and found **no** duplicate in the db, suggesting MERGE is properly inserting/updating the data, adding HOLDLOCK simply causes a deadlock on a highly multi-threaded scenario (I already covered this possibility/problem before posting the question)

Comment: @Jason: I can appreciate your position.  However, considering this is entirely reproducible by others given the scenario you described then it certainly appears to be your issue.  In the second link above the following statement is crucial: **"The HOLDLOCK hint was still needed, though, because *MERGE otherwise releases the update key lock before the insert*. "**

Comment: It doesn't convince me, if true, (1) by simply removing the unique index, I should see duplicate, yet there is none, (2) I have tried adding the HOLDLOCK and it has caused deadlocks which was what I was trying to fix originally.  I have found a work around to this, but I'd like to see what other solution will actually work that doesn't involve re-introducing deadlocks

Comment: 1) Not necessarily.   By dropping the index of the field you are merging on you are moving the most time consuming work from the `INSERT` operation to the `SELECT` part.  Basically, it doesn't have to wait in the INSERT portion to update the index etc.  However a wait is introduced in the SELECT part because it now has to look at all the records in the table (not index) to pull out what it needs.  In short, it just changes the timing a bit which is likely enough to not see the issue in a limited test environment

Comment: What you say makes sense, though I am still a bit skeptical.  I ran my tests using a pool of 1k GUID's over 10k iterations, then again with a pool of 10k GUID's over 1M iterations, in both cases I ran it numerous times, all successful, perhaps it was luck, but perhaps not  :)

Comment: Your first comment about the HOLDLOCK causing deadlock is disturbing if it is true.  I wonder, in reality, how many people besides Dan Guzman have actually stress tested the merge statement with the hold lock.  Perhaps your stress test is different in some way.  http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx