# Would `merge` statement guarantee the same value of a `default current_timestamp` column for all inserted rows?

Tags: sql-server, merge

I believe even within a transaction, a bunch of the insertion to a table with a `default current_timestamp` column, might have different values base on the row creation time but I'm not sure how *atomic* the `merge` statement is:

[Is MERGE an atomic statement in SQL2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871644/is-merge-an-atomic-statement-in-sql2008/9871942#9871942)

Here's my test script:

- Code

  ```
  if type_id(N'ValuableRow') is not null 
      drop type ValuableRow

  create type ValuableRow as table (
      JustAValue nvarchar(max)
  )

  drop table if exists 
      TestTable

  create table TestTable(
      JustAValue nvarchar(max) 
      , Birth datetime2 default current_timestamp
  ) 

  go

  --// delete TestTable

  insert TestTable(JustAValue)
      values ('1234'), ('5678')

  declare 
      @rows ValuableRow, @alsoRows ValuableRow

  insert @rows(JustAValue)
      values ('abcd'), ('1234'), ('5678'), ('wxyz')

  merge 
      TestTable y
  using
      @rows x
  on (y.JustAValue=x.JustAValue)  
  when not matched then  
  insert (JustAValue) 
      values (JustAValue)
  output 
      inserted.JustAValue
  into 
      @alsoRows
  ;

  select 
      *
  from 
      @alsoRows

  select 
      *
  from 
      TestTable
  ```

and the result shows:

[image]

Apparently it's not enough to tell what would be the case if the operation took longer execution time, I'm wondering would `merge` still make all the inserted rows with the same creation time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time entered as the default will be the same for all rows irrespective of how long it takes for the `MERGE`.

This is nothing to do with atomicity of `MERGE`.

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ends up the calling `GETDATE()` function. `GETDATE()` is a [runtime constant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions/). Each individual reference in the plan is guaranteed to have the same value for the whole statement duration (though if a plan has multiple references to `GETDATE()` these will be two different runtime constants and can be evaluated at different times).

The execution plan here just has a single reference to the function. It is calculated once and given the expression label `Expr1010`

```
StmtText
  |--Table Insert(OBJECT:(@alsoRows), SET:([JustAValue] = [tempdb].[dbo].[TestTable].[JustAValue] as [y].[JustAValue]))
       |--Table Merge(OBJECT:([tempdb].[dbo].[TestTable] AS [y]), SET:([tempdb].[dbo].[TestTable].[JustAValue] as [y].[JustAValue] = @rows.[JustAValue] as [x].[JustAValue],[tempdb].[dbo].[TestTable].[Birth] as [y].[Birth] = [Expr1010]) ACTION:([Action1009]))
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1010]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime2(7),getdate(),0)))
                 |--Table Spool
                      |--Filter(WHERE:([Action1009] IS NOT NULL))
                           |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Action1009]=ForceOrder(CASE WHEN [TrgPrb1007] IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE (4) END)))
                                |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([x].[JustAValue]))
                                     |--Table Scan(OBJECT:(@rows AS [x]))
                                     |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([TrgPrb1007]=(1)))
                                          |--Filter(WHERE:([tempdb].[dbo].[TestTable].[JustAValue] as [y].[JustAValue]=@rows.[JustAValue] as [x].[JustAValue]))
                                               |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([tempdb].[dbo].[TestTable] AS [y]))
```

`RAND()` is also a runtime constant and one where it is easier to see this behaviour in practice as it doesn't depend upon engineering a long running statement.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(X FLOAT DEFAULT RAND());

MERGE INTO @T 
USING sys.objects o ON o.object_id = X
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT *
FROM @T; /*All rows will have the same value*/
```

Comment: I'm also wondering how do you generate the text version of the  execution plan ..

Comment: @KenKin - `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON` then execute the statements that you want the text plan for. Though this just generates the plan rather than executing them

Answer (score 0):

Current_timestamp will not guarantee that all the rows inserted in a long running merge statement have the same time stamp. If you would like all the rows to have the same time stamp, I would suggest storing a time stamp in a variable right before the merge. Then you can use the timestamp variable as part of the insert statement.

Comment: What I'm wondering is just the necessity of doing this; dun know if `megre`'ve already done it under the hood.

Comment: The answer is wrong. there are only two basic answers. The time is guaranteed to be the same or the time is not guaranteed to be the same and this picks the wrong one

Comment: This is what I thought too but back when we were still using sql 2008 (as mentioned on the question), we ran into an issue where an interface was doing a giant merge around midnight (don’t get me started on why they coded it like that). Anyways, some records ended up with the time stamp of the next day and caused people to think the interface failed. Anyways, bottom line is that if that is no longer an issue, then I stand gladly corrected. I will still probably use a variable when it is truly important that all records get a constant value, but that may be just my paranoia at this point :)