# SQL Server insert into with an indexed column

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way around the unique index? I want my query to continue to run even after it hits the duplicate key value. The information that is a duplicate, I do not want to insert. However, there could be data after the duplicate that is not a duplicate. The unique indexed column is `WebQuoteNo`. I have previously pulled quotes from SalesOrderData and now I want to pull any NEW quotes and insert into OrderHeader. I tried the EXCEPT statement but got the same error. "Cannot insert duplicate key"

```
INSERT INTO OrderHeader (WebQuoteNo, Date, OrderType, ListTotal, DiscountTotal, WebEmail)
    SELECT        
        WebQuoteNo, Date, OrderType, ListTotal, discount AS DiscountTotal, WebEmail
    FROM          
        SalesOrderData
```

Here are the two tables. The Quotes from 7/26/2022 need to be add to the OrderHeader table.

[This is what my table currently look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RM5p.png)

Comment: Fix your query so it *doesn't* return duplicate values. That's a problem of the SELECT query. `that is a duplicate,` how do you determine that? Based on which columns? Use that criteria to eliminate duplicates from the start.

Comment: In brief: **NO** - there's no way *around a unique index* - and that's a **GOOD thing!!** It was put there **for a reason** - respect that reason, it's up to **YOU** not to violate that constraint .....

Comment: On the other hand, what happens if there are duplicate quotes with different dates and values? Which ones would you keep?

Comment: Can I use Merge? The problem is the table OrderHeader, the PK is an auto number.

Comment: We can't guess why there are duplicate WebQuoteNo values, what these rows look like and which ones you want to insert. You can write a query that pick the first row by date, last by date, pick the MIN or MAX values of each column. What *do* you want to do?

Comment: @Pattie `MERGE` is a coverup hack. And won't work - but it will do so in unusual ways. The whole point is that you *shouldn't* use hacks to ignore errors. If you store the *wrong* quote line, your company or customer will pay the consequences.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added this statement, got the same error                        
 EXCEPT
SELECT        WebQuoteNo,Date, OrderType, ListTotal, DiscountTotal, WebEmail
FROM          OrderHeader

Comment: I didn't ask for a statement. I asked which row you want to preserve. If you don't know that, you can't write any statement

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos     Okay so the table SalesOrderData has ALL of the WebQuotes theat have been pulled in using an API. Then  the quotes are inserted into Order Header. I would like to preserve the data in SalesOrderData for history.

Comment: If there are multiple rows with the same Web Quote number, which one do you want to preserve?

Comment: There are no duplicates in SalesOrderData. When i an pulling from SalesOrderData, I am using the entire table. But some of the orders have already been insereted into the OrderHeader and some have not.

Comment: Okay. I will edit again. I apologize for the info not being comlete. I am new to SQL and also new to this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three things that can cause a unique constraint/index violation:

1. You are trying to insert a single row where the values defined for the columns in the constraint are the same in a row that already exists in the target.
2. You are trying to insert multiple rows that violate the constraint even though a row doesn't already exist in the target.
3. Both.

Let's say you have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderHeader
(
  WebQuoteNo varchar(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Date       date,
  OrderType  char(1),
  ListTotal  decimal(12,2),
  Discount   decimal(12,2)
);
```

The way you typically avoid 1. is:

```
INSERT dbo.OrderHeader
(
  WebQuoteNo, Date, OrderType, ListTotal, Discount
)
SELECT 
  WebQuoteNo, Date, OrderType, ListTotal, Discount
FROM dbo.SalesOrderData AS s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM dbo.OrderHeader AS h WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE h.WebQuoteNo = s.WebQuoteNo
);
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=904120d23805e138bb6253e89d379163)

If you also need to guard against 2., you need to figure out which duplicate you want to keep. You can use something like this:

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT WebQuoteNo, /* other columns, */
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WebQuoteNo 
      ORDER BY <some other deterministic criteria, maybe DATE?>
  FROM dbo.SalesOrderData AS s
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1
      FROM dbo.OrderHeader AS h WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
      WHERE h.WebQuoteNo = s.WebQuoteNo
  )
  -- and other criteria
)
INSERT dbo.OrderHeader(WebQuoteNo /* , other columns */)
  SELECT WebQuoteNo /* , other columns */
  FROM src 
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

Before you even think about using some suggestion that flings `MERGE` over the wall as a solution to an `INSERT` problem without also talking about concurrency and isolation, please read [all of these posts](https://sqlblog.org/merge) and to understand the purpose of the locking hints applied here see [this post about upserts](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern).

Answer (score -3):

**Assumption 1:** You have a process that PULL sales data, and that data cause violation of PK for sales header record

**Assumption 2:** Sales data most commonly put a record per item, since when you get a batch of records, those may contain duplicate of header

**Assumption 3:** Sales often do corrections and may send same record with new price (total) again. And again try to break constraint.

**Assumption 4:** Since you pulling batches this is nightly process and most likely during run users are not using system

**Option 1:** Will fix **Assumption 2**, use **DISTINCT** for inserted rows.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT       
        WebQuoteNo, Date, OrderType, ListTotal, discount AS DiscountTotal, WebEmail
    FROM          
        SalesOrderData ) as a
```

**Option 2:** If you suffer from sales data update **Assumption 3**, you most likely can use **MERGE**, if **Assumption 4** is correct.

The short how to is here.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/

MERGE has following caveats that you should fully accept before trying:

1. Most likely you will need to fully lock table during update process, so if it is impacting users and that is unacceptable "MERGE" is not your option.
2. If you cannot fully lock table you will need to follow suggestion from Aaron Bertrand here https://sqlblog.org/merge and be super cautios.

In General MERGE work well for nightly process, during non-business hours.

Comment: That's not what merge does. Using it like that can have some very amusing results (for others). MERGE is *not* atomic

Comment: Well, merge allow you to skip both update and delete if criteria matches. It doesn’t force you to perform all operations. Since you can use CTE or table variables to provide data..

Comment: And I disagree on atomic - see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871644/is-merge-an-atomic-statement-in-sql2008

Comment: Also, before you start flinging around MERGE suggestions and stating that it is atomic and completely isolated as a unit without also mentioning that this is only true if you lock the target table with serializable (which completely kills concurrency to avoid race conditions), please read [all of these posts](https://sqlblog.org/merge).

Comment: @Maksym you didn't just post that in a comment thread with two SQL Server MVPs (one former). Especially when one of them suffered for years to understand why he randomly got duplicate key errors when there were no duplicates. With explicit transactions. Turns out I had an `ID=source.ID` clause in my `UPDATE` clause. When that happened with large tables and parallelization kicked in, SQL Server would generate identical "updated" rows. You misunderstood what that answer says

Comment: Ill modify answer and provide more details on usage and caveats. Np. Both (former) just to be clear :)

Comment: @Maksym you should probably read Aaron's articles on the subject first. Whatever you write references them directly or indirectly

Comment: @AaronBertrand I tried to use your example and I get the error                                 
Invalid column name 'DiscountTotal'.
Invalid column name 'ShipToNo'.                                                                                            Is there a reason it doesn't like these two columns? They are definetly there and I double checked the spelling.

Comment: @Pattie I believe that was comment to me, corrected

Comment: This still fails in at least two ways (the OP says there aren't duplicates in the source, which means there must be at least one WebQuoteNo in the source that already exists in the target. Which means applying `DISTINCT *` isn't going to solve that collision, as I already mentioned before. Second, [subqueries and derived tables need an alias](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5910dff80a5ee0b0fde4e0162188293).

Comment: If he got collision between source and target, most likely these are updates after fiscal period closing, which make things much worse. Most likely the last two columns in duplicated records are different as well, and as a result just inserting without updating duplicated will be most likely wrong.

Comment: No. This comment was for @aaronBertrand. It was his that I tried.

Comment: @Pattie Again, can't read minds, so I have no idea what actual query you tried to run. Maybe you could try [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=904120d23805e138bb6253e89d379163).