# Add a IF ...ELSE statement to stored procedure to skip duplicate primary keys

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a try catch in my physical C# code that just skips this insert process when a error accrues and continues the loop to fill the database. However this is bad coding practice.

So I would like to add an `IF` statement to the stored procedure below that will just skip if a primary key is already there. My primary key is `@id`.

How can I go about this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProc
    (
    @id int, 
    @to nvarchar(100), 
    @from nvarchar(100), 
    @subject nvarchar(100), 
    @date datetime
    )
AS
    INSERT INTO Emails_Log (Email_ID, e_To, e_From, e_Subject, e_Date) 
    VALUES (@id, @to, @from, @subject, @date)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProc
    (
    @id int, 
    @to nvarchar(100), 
    @from nvarchar(100), 
    @subject nvarchar(100), 
    @date datetime
    )
    AS
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Emails_Log
                    WHERE Email_ID = @ID)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Emails_Log (Email_ID, e_To, e_From, e_Subject, e_Date) 
            VALUES (@id, @to, @from, @subject, @date)
    END
```

If you actually want to update record if already exists and insert if not, the pattern is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProc
    (
       @id int, 
       @to nvarchar(100), 
       @from nvarchar(100), 
       @subject nvarchar(100), 
       @date datetime
    )
    AS
       UPDATE Emails_Log
          SET e_To = @to, 
              e_From = @from, 
              e_Subject = @subject, 
              e_Date = @date
        WHERE Email_ID = @ID
       -- If there was no update it means that @ID does not exist,
       -- So we proceede with insert
       IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
       BEGIN
          INSERT INTO Emails_Log (Email_ID, e_To, e_From, e_Subject, e_Date) 
               VALUES (@id, @to, @from, @subject, @date)
       END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProc
    (
    @id int, 
    @to nvarchar(100), 
    @from nvarchar(100), 
    @subject nvarchar(100), 
    @date datetime
    )
    AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * From Emails_Log Where Email_ID = @id)
    UPDATE Emails_Log (Email_ID, e_To, e_From, e_Subject, e_Date) 
            SET e_To = @to, e_From = @from, e_Subject = @subject, e_Date = @date
            WHERE Email_ID = @id
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO Emails_Log (Email_ID, e_To, e_From, e_Subject, e_Date) 
            VALUES (@id, @to, @from, @subject, @date)
```

Another way to do this would be with [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command.

Look at [this thread on SO to know more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639854/check-if-a-row-exists-otherwise-insert).

Comment: set ...? would ((at)id, (at)to, (at)from, (at)subject, (at)date) go in there?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure InsertUpdateProc, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '('.  : I got this error

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the existence of a record in table and 
insert the record in one statement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProc
(
@id int, 
@to nvarchar(100), 
@from nvarchar(100), 
@subject nvarchar(100), 
@date datetime
)
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Email_ID From Emails_Log Where Email_ID = @id)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Emails_Log (Email_ID, e_To, e_From, e_Subject, e_Date) 
        VALUES (@id, @to, @from, @subject, @date)
END
```