# Is there a get-or-create (lazy loading?) idiom in SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)
>   [Check if a row exists, otherwise insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639854/check-if-a-row-exists-otherwise-insert)

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, C# .NET 4.0 (and LINQ).

I want to get or create a row in a table and then append a string to one of its columns.

I'm wondering if there's a best practice for this kind of idiom, or if SQL offers this out of the box?

Somehow `transaction start -> select -> insert or update -> transaction end` doesn't seem elegant enough...

Comment: you should show your tried code

Comment: i'm just wondering if there's a more general solution to this problem