# MySQL if value exists select else insert

Tags: mysql

What is the most efficient mysql query to SELECT from a table IF a value already exists ELSE INSERT?

I have already tried several options but can't find something that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Stackoverflow and dont know how to tag a question as duplicate.

But i think there is a really similar question with plenty of answers. Give a look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488355/if-exists-then-select-else-insert-and-then-select)

[Possible solution]

You could insert if it not exists and then select it.

```
INSERT INTO Test(Key_Value , Name , ...) VALUES(@Key_Value ,@Name,..) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Test WHERE KeyValue = @KeyValue);

SELECT Name FROM Test WHERE Key_Value = @Key_Value
```

Comment: That answer is for MS SQL so doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: It's really similar actually. I will edit my answer a bit.